# Echad - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

**Who knows one?**

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. In about a day, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/420/shnayim-mi-yodeya

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Brand spanking cool new jewish Q & A site.

Comment: Panderer. You win *this time*.

Answer (score 25):

Umm, 2 years later, and no one has gone with:

- One is Hashem, the Holy One, Blessed Be He, Creator of Heaven and Earth.

Answer (score 9):

1=10

(cf. אבן עזרא לשמות ג:יד)

Comment: 3:15 in my edition. Heavy, man.

Answer (score 7):

[Shabbos 28b](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14314&st=&pgnum=57) says that the bull that Adam Harishon brought as a sacrifice had one horn.

Answer (score 6):

1 is the amount of wives you can have post Cheirem D'Rabbeinu Gershom in the communities that accepted it.

Answer (score 6):

One is the number by which gematrias can be off and only elicit small groans.

Comment: This answer would be more valuable if you could [edit] in a source supporting it.

Answer (score 4):

echad (1)=13 (aleph=1, chet=8, dalet=4)
Thirteen are the midos of Hashem!

Comment: You think you can skip to the end?

Comment: That's Maharal.  Showing how 13 goes to 1.  12 needs 1 to even it out to 13, to a complete 1.  Like the 12 months need an extra to make 1 solar year (on average), or the 12 tribes need Jacob to declare "Shema Yisrael ... Hashem ECHAD."

Comment: See also: http://astrotorah.weeklyshtikle.com/2010/03/thirteenth-tribe-of-yisrael.html

Comment: What happened to no lazy gematria?

Answer (score 2):

Shallum son of Jabesh reigned as king for one month in Samaria ([Kings II 15:13](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt09b15.htm#13)).

Ahazia of Judah reigned for one year, ([Kings II 8:26](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt09b08.htm#26)).

Answer (score 2):

One is the kapores of the aron.

The Kapores is unique. There are multiple krashim, adanim, and badim, the paroches had a pair, and [every other kli](http://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/fleisher/archives/teruma59.htm) was duplicated multiple times by Shlomo HaMelech except the aron (Moshav Zekenim Parshas Terumah 25:21). But the structure of the aron itself is similar to that of the mizbach hanechoshes - a wooden box covered with metal. The only differences are the size and orientation of the box!

Only the kapores and the menorah were hammered directly out of gold, but the Shlomo had 10 duplicates of the menorah made, but he could not do so for the aron and the Kapores.

So the only truly unique piece is the kapores. Why?

Because the [two angels facing each other](http://shulchanaruchharav.com/Home-Database/docs/6.%20Teruma-Mamar.pdf) represent and reflect the relationship between Klal Yisroel and Hashem. (See Yuma 54a)

We have two sets of luchos - the whole and the broken. There is the tzintenes hamon that testifies to the chessed of Hashem, but Chazal say that the mon melted and was drunk by the animals so that the umos ha'olam could experience it. All of these fill the inside of the aron because they form the foundation for the kapores: the representation of the one truly unique thing in the briyah - Hashem's loving relationship with US!

Answer (score 0):

1 torah was given to the jews on har sinai

Answer (score 0):

ONE is the days of Shavuos in Eretz Yisroel!