# Shnayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows two?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. In about a day, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/431/shelosha-mi-yodeya

Comment: Prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/378/echad-mi-yodeya/379

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to one Ladino version of Echad Mi yodea 
(there is more than one version) 
"Two are Moshe and Aharon"
which resolves the seeming duplication
of "Two are the Tablets" and "Ten are the Commandments"

Comment: Not just the Ladino version; at least some of the Arabic versions - including the one that I know from family tradition (my mother's family hail from Aleppo) - have the same thing. (Other differences from the "standard" Echad Mi Yodea: "seven are the days of the Chuppah" and "thirteen is the age of putting on tefillin.")

Comment: barrygoodlife, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks very much for your informative entry in our ongoing number contest! Stay tuned for future numbers. Please consider clicking "register," above, to create an account. This will give you access to all of mi.yodeya's features and will allow you to claim full credit for your contributions.

Comment: Alex, it is very possible that the Arabic version was translated from the Ladino.

Comment: @Yahu or vice versa

Answer (score 11):

Two are:

- Moshiach ben David and Moshiach ben Yosef
- Batei Mikdashim ([So far!!](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/558/883))
- The *sets* of Luchos (as well as the number in each set)
- Zugos!

  - Yose ben Yoezer and Yose ben Yochanan
  - Yehoshua ben Perachya and Nittai HaArbeli
  - Yehudah ben Tabbai and Shimon ben Shetach
  - Shmaya and Avtalion
  - Hillel and Shammai
- Sons of:

  - Rochel (Yosef and Binyamin)
  - Rivka (Yaakov and Eisav)
  - Avraham (Yitzchak and Yishmael) (At least the main ones (However you define main))
  - Amram (Aharon and Moshe)

Answer (score 9):

2 is the minimum number for a plural word that is *darshoned* (expounded) in the Talmud.

Comment: is it ever a number other than two?

Answer (score 8):

2 is the number of Pesach Sedarim for those who live outside of Israel.

Answer (score 7):

Two are the Chief Rabbis of Israel.

And, as as a result of the settlement brokered by Rabbi Isacc Elchanan Spektor in 1835, two were the Rosh Yeshivas of Volozhin.

Answer (score 7):

סימני כשרות לדגים - Signs that a fish is Kosher

1. סנפיר - fins
2. קשקשת - scales

Answer (score 6):

Two (ט"ו) equals 15. (Suggested by my 9-year-old son.)

Comment: Nice! The family that yodeyas together, uhh, TBD, but it's good and together. Oh, and hold that thought...

Answer (score 6):

Two are the years that the kings of the House of Saul  reigned (see: [I Samuel 13:1](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Samuel.13.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and [II Samuel 2:10](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Samuel.2.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

Answer (score 5):

Two are the months before a wolf is born.

(See Dewey, T. and J. Smith. 2002. ["**Canis lupus**", Animal Diversity Web](http://animaldiversity.ummz.umich.edu/site/accounts/information/Canis_lupus.html). Accessed March 17, 2010)

(Comparison with Talmud Bavli [Bechorot (PDF)](http://halakhah.com/pdf/kodoshim/Bechoroth.pdf) [8a](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=4902&size=1) requires [investigation](http://www.rationalistjudaism.com/2009/07/snake-gestation.html).)

Comment: Oh man, that's good...

Comment: Thanks! I don't think you're in danger of being out-cusped, though.

Comment: This could do with some better explanation of what exactly is "two" and what is Jewish about it.

Answer (score 5):

Two are the wives of Lemech, and Hevel according to one medrash ([Bereishis Rabbah 22:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.22.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

Answer (score 4):

סימני כשרות לבהמות - Signs that an animal is Kosher

1. מעלה גרה - chews cud
2. מפרסת פרסה - split hooves

Comment: 3 Shosa'at Shesa' (something else to do with the feet). I'm pretty sure this is treated as a third category by most rishonim...

Answer (score 4):

Shnei Luchos Habris

Answer (score 3):

The gemara in [Bava Kamma 29b](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Kamma.29b.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) states:

**2 things** that aren't "technically" in a person's property but (in terms of halachic responsibilities) the Torah makes it as if it ***is*** in a person's property:

- a pit a person dug in the public domain ([Choshen Mishpat 410:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Choshen_Mishpat.410?lang=bi))
- *chametz* that remains in a person's possession on Erev Passover from noon onwards ([Orach Chaim 443:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.443.1?lang=bi))

Answer (score 2):

A dream dreamt twice is a sign that it will be fulfilled ([Brachos 55b](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.55b.20?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

Answer (score 2):

2 hours of daylight were lost on account of Yaakov and (those) two were regained on his account. - [Bereshit Rabbah 68:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.68.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) ([Bereshit 28:11](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.28.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), [32:32](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.32.32?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

Answer (score 2):

2- are the instances where the Torah accepts the testimony of just one witness (see: **Rambam**, [Hilchos Eidus 5:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Testimony.5.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)):

- a) by a Sotah- so that she does not drink the bitter waters
- b) by an *eglah arufah*- to prevent its neck from being broken

---

(d'rabbanan we also accept one witness who's testifying that a woman's husband died)

Comment: While the Rambam says the above, he also says in Hilchos Eidus 11:7 https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Testimony.11.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en  "one witness is believed in *issurin*" - curious how this seeming discrepancy/ contradiction can be resolved (will leave this here as a comment until I can figure out the difference via a separate question)

Answer (score 1):

2 is the number of *first* Orthodox female rabbis.

http://jwablog.jwa.org/node/23

http://morethodoxy.org/2010/01/28/mahara%E2%80%9Dt-to-rabba/

Comment: Good job following directions. You'd have won if your second source had the word "first" in it.

Comment: darn it!! I definitely could have found a better source.  Oh well.  It was fun playing.

Comment: It depends who is defining the term "Orthodox".

Comment: Also "first" and "rabbi," apparently. I'm not aware of "female" being disputed in either case.

Comment: Neshamah is a feminine word, so spiritually speaking all rabbi's are female. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Two women were haughty and had unpleasant names - Devorah ("bee") and Chuldah ("mole")

[Gemara Megillah 14b](https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.14b.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

Answer (score 1):

TWO days of Shavuos outside Eretz Yisroel!

Answer (score 1):

1. Torah Shebichsav + Torah Shebal Peh
2. Yitzchok + Yishmoel
3. Yaakov + Eisav
4. Shevatim Not On The Other Side Of The River (not counting Shevet Levi)
5. Yomim Noraim
6. Sedarim in Chutz Laaretz
7. Days of Shavuos
8. Talmud Bavli + Talmud Yerushalmi
9. Days of Rosh Hashanah
10. Days of Shemini Atzeres in Chutz Laaretz

Answer (score 1):

Two are the number of eyes that [Shimshon sought revenge for](https://www.sefaria.org/Judges.16.28) from the Pelishtim.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken it's specifically one of of two eyes and not both...

Comment: @Shababnik One nekamah, two eyes ;)

Answer (score 1):

- Two are the pairs, male and female, of [impure] animals brought into the ark. ~ Genesis 7:2.

Answer (score 0):

TWO days of Rosh Hashanah! 222222

Answer (score 0):

Two is “zachor” ([Shmos 20:8](https://mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t0220.htm)) and “shamor” ([Dvarim 5:11](https://mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t0505.htm)), two mitzvos in reference to Shabbos.

Two is the number of neshamos a Jew has during Shabbos: their regular neshama and a neshama yeseira, an extra Shabbos soul ([Beitza 16a](https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=8&daf=16&format=pdf)).