# Pas (Pat) vs Lechem

Tags: words, bread

In Tanach/Mishna/Gemara sometimes the word **Pas** is used, and sometimes **Lechem**.

Do Chazal say anything about when and why one is used vs the other?

**Edit**
I was asked for an example: In Mishna Brachos Chapter 6 Mishna 1 it says

```
"... except for bread [Pas] [where one says] 'Hamotzi Lechem min Ha'aretz' ..."
```

(sorry - not sure how to type Hebrew easily.)

Comment: Can you provide some examples?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/53346/759

Answer (score 3):

The word פת means "piece". (As I don't believe in coincidence, I think the English word "piece" may have come from the Hebrew, in some way!)

See Radak on Genesis 18:5:1 (Sefaria English translation) - Hebrew & English excerpted by me:

> ואקחה פת לחם, כי הנה אברהם אמר פת לחם **שפירושו חתיכת לחם** ולא אמר
> לחם כמו שאמר מעט מים כמו שפירשנו. ואקחה פת לחם
>
> Avraham spoke about a **piece** of bread, whereas in fact he served
> a sumptuous meal.  He had even understated the amount of bread he
> would serve by not saying ואקח לחם, but ואקחה פת לחם, a reference to
> less than a whole loaf.

Further support for the concept that the word means "piece" is Leviticus 2:6 (Sefaria English):

> פָּת֤וֹת אֹתָהּ֙ פִּתִּ֔ים וְיָצַקְתָּ֥ עָלֶ֖יהָ שָׁ֑מֶן מִנְחָ֖ה
> הִֽוא׃ (ס)
>
> Thou shalt break it in pieces, and pour oil thereon; it is a
> meal-offering.

As your question appears to be general, it seems that Tanach's use of the term refers to the term "piece". See Ruth 2:14:

> וַיֹּאמֶר֩ לָ֨ה בֹ֜עַז לְעֵ֣ת הָאֹ֗כֶל גֹּ֤שִֽׁי הֲלֹם֙ **וְאָכַ֣לְתְּ
> מִן־הַלֶּ֔חֶם וְטָבַ֥לְתְּ פִּתֵּ֖ךְ** בַּחֹ֑מֶץ וַתֵּ֙שֶׁב֙ מִצַּ֣ד
> הַקּֽוֹצְרִ֔ים וַיִּצְבָּט־לָ֣הּ קָלִ֔י וַתֹּ֥אכַל וַתִּשְׂבַּ֖ע
> וַתֹּתַֽר׃
>
> And Boaz said unto her at meal-time: ‘Come hither, and eat **of the
> bread, and dip thy morsel** in the vinegar.’ And she sat beside the
> reapers; and they reached her parched corn, and she did eat and was
> satisfied, and left thereof

.

The above example, in separating the 2 terms "pat" and "lechem" makes it pretty clear that "pat" means "piece".

I am assuming that when both Mishnah, and in your case your quoting Shulchan Aruch, they use the term "pat" when meaning eating a slice or piece of bread. I think "lechem" would be used when it refers to "bread" as a general food, for example, if they were talking about what grains would be considered "bread".