# Aesthetics and chukoseihem

Tags: halacha, minhag, avodah-zarah, art, hukot-hagoyim

In general, there is a prohibition to adopt practices from other cultures (See, e.g., [Maimonides' Laws of Idolatry 11](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/1411.htm); see also [here](http://olamot.net/shiur/%D7%91%D7%97%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%94%D7%9D-%D7%9C%D7%90-%D7%AA%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95)) if there is no clear, reasonable, non-idolatrous justification for the practice (e.g. knocking on wood) for fear that it has its roots indeed from the rituals of idolatry.  I believe this is the case regardless of whether or not the actual origins are known, provided there isn't a halachically-significant reasonable justification (e.g. flossing[[?]](https://www.webmd.com/oral-health/news/20160802/is-all-that-flossing-really-worth-it#1)).

What about specific  aesthetic patterns or symbols that have been in use since antiquity (e.g. [celtic knots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celtic_knot))? What if the common practice in the observant Jewish world has already been to incorporate these patterns (e.g. [braided loaves](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34704/why-are-challot-traditionally-braided/55771#55771))? What if there is significant evidence that the origins do indeed have pagan ritualistic undertones?

Comment: As you noted in the comments there, the notion of pagan origins of braided loaves is dubious.

Comment: @Fred I don't know if I would say it's dubious. That particular "authority" is not that credible, but he's not the first to make the claim. And, when a tradition is not already Jewish, as I noted, our criterion for rejection includes even just a doubt of idolatrous origin.

Comment: I've always been under the impression that knocking on wood was a reference to the wood of the cross, which would clearly be idolatrous. And why can't a practice have multiple origins, being both reasonable and non-idolatrous from one source but then ALSO having a  separate idolatrous reason (the most straight forward example is a practice that originated in two locations separately)?

Answer (score 2):

I just came across one [relevant reference](http://bdld.info/2015/04/08/copying-cruciform-churches-campanas-circuses-and-colosseums/) regarding synagogue architecture

> ועל אותן אשר מתכוונים לעשות בנין בשמונה צלעות (ומכל שכן בארבעה צלעות)
>   כדמות היכלי הגוים, עליהם אני קורא וישכח ישראל עושהו ויבן היכלות ע”ש,
>   ובפרט בבנינים כמו היכלי עכו”ם יש גם כן לאו של תורה, ובחוקותיהם לא
>   תלכו, כמו שנתבאר רמב”ם פרק י”א מהלכות עכו”ם הלכה א’, וביו”ד סימן קע”ח
>   דהבונה היכל כבנין היכלות שלהם עובר על לאו של תורה ולוקה ע”ש, ועיין
>   ראב”ד שם דהוא הדין שלא יעשה צורות כמו שהם עושים, או שלא יעשה סימן לקבץ
>   בו הרבים, כמו שהם עושים ע”ש, ועיין ט”ז שם סימן קע”ח ס”ק ג’ שכתב שיש
>   לאסור כל אלו ע”ש

מנחת קנאות, נדפס בשו”ת מוהר”ץ (זאלקווא תר”י), עמוד תתקצא

> And regarding those who intend to build an eight-winged structure (and certainly a 4-winged structure) like the form of the gentile halls, about them I read "And Israel forgot its Maker and built halls", see there. And particularly with regard to structures like idolators' halls there's additionally a biblical prohibition "and in their mores though shall not go" as explained in Maimonides chapter 11 in the Laws of Idolatry Law 1 and in Yoreh Deah 178 that one who builds a hall like their halls violates a bibilical prohibition... See also the Raavad there that it is also the case that one is forbidden to make forms like they do... and see the Taz there 178:3 who wrote that all these should be forbidden...

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @Ploni I don't think it (fully) answers the question, but I think it's at least a relevant source inasmuch as the structures he's describing sound symmetric and aesthetic, and he nonetheless rules that they are forbidden since they are similar to the symmetric/aesthetic structures of idolators.