# Can I have flowers planted on my grave?

Tags: halacha, death, cemetery-grave, agriculture, hukot-hagoyim

[Why don't Jewish people put flowers on graves?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/62166/6788)
Asks about a visitor leaving flowers on a grave. 
The reason we don’t is that it’s “chukas hagoyim”

Does the same logic apply for a the dead person themselves. Meaning could I request that flowers be planted on my grave. Just because I think flowers are pretty and if I’m going to be paying for a random plot of land I might as well get some use out of it.

Or is there any other halachik reason I can’t have flowers planted on my grave?

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56872/aesthetics-and-chukoseihem

Comment: Why should chukas hagoyim not apply? The deceased isn’t the one who’s putting the flowers there – the living people who are still obligated are.