# Is a kohen who embarrasses someone publicly prohibited to duchen?

Tags: kohen-priest, birchas-kohanim, embarrassment

Since embarrassing one in public is considerred like murder and one should give up their life rather than transgress (Bava Metzia 59B, see Tosfas Sotah 10B on top), does this mean a kohen cannot *duchen* if he embarrasses someone publicly?

Comment: If being angry is like worshipping idols, does it mean we should stone each other? Many [similar] statements have educational (non-Halachic) purposes only.

Comment: Yes I know not everything can be taken literally - but embarrassing others publicly some do consider like murder. Public shame being like murder is on a higher level than being angry is like avoda zara

Comment: @Ed How do you know it's on a higher level? Including that in your question would greatly increase its value to the community

Comment: Besides the above comments, there's also the issue that the question gives me no reason to think there's any connection between murder and duchening. −1.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53598/public-shaming-cardinal-sin

Answer (score 9):

[Responsa Shevet Halevi 8:172](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1418&st=%D7%A4%D7%A0%D7%99%20%D7%97%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95&pgnum=158&hilite=) rules that such a person is allowed to duchen, because the verse that is the source of the prohibition, as well as the Rambam and Shulchan Aruch imply that the issue is that hands used to murder cannot also be used to duchen. In this case however the 'murder' was not done with his hands, so the prohibition would not apply.