# What are the 3 shvuot that are d'oraisa?

Tags: talmud-gemara, talmud-bavli

I know that a shvuat heses is drabanan.
I think modeh b'miktzas is one, and that shvuat hashomrim is another, but what is the third? (and are the 2 I mentioned correct)

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya alicht and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Note amongst others the focus on English as the main site language - ideally a non Hebrew speaker would understand what we are speaking about (although I agree it is harder to apply to this question, but please bear in mind for the future). Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The three categories of biblically prescribed oaths are 1) an oath of a bailee ("Shevuat haShomerim"), 2) an oath to defend a partial monetary rejection ("Modeh beMiktzat"), and 3) an oath to counter a solitary witness ("Eid Echad").

See Rambam, Laws of Shevuot 11:5

Comment: Shvuat Haedut? shvuat sota?

Comment: @kouty Shevuat haedut is a voluntary oath. If you lie about one there are consequences.

Comment: OK I understand