# Arba'a Asar - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows fourteen?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. After about one business day, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: [ארבע עשר טוטיא](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p1pD89oJjsg)

Comment: @DoubleAA http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%98%D7%95%D7%98%D7%95 ?

Comment: Prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/716/shelosha-asar-mi-yodeya?r=SearchResults

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/808/chamisha-asar-mi-yodeya?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fourteen are the [books of the -- Rambam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mishneh_Torah).
(Well, in the work considered his latest and greatest, anyway.  Or "fourteen are the books of the MishnahTorah."  Which version is worse on the rhythm?)

Fourteen are the number of [solid ingredients in the Biblical incense](http://bible.ort.org/books/pentd2.asp?ACTION=displaypage&BOOK=2&CHAPTER=30#C1810) (according to Rabbi Nathan the Babylonian).

Fourteen are the minutes after sunset at which point I don't think anyone non-Hassidic will allow you to recite Mincha.  (The absolute latest I'd heard was 13.5 minutes.)

Comment: I would sing it as "Fourteen are the books of the Mishnah. Torah." repeating the tune on "Mishnah" for "Torah."

Comment: Isn't the proper pronunciation "Mishne Torah"?

Comment: Yes, but that wouldn't be as funny.

Answer (score 7):

Fourteen is the number of days that a mother is tamei after the birth of a baby girl (Lev. 12:5 - in this week's parsha).

Answer (score 6):

Fourteen is the day of the month of Iyar when the "Second Pesach" can be offered, if one missed the first one. (May Hashem grant us to be able to do so this year!)

Comment: Amen! Why should we be held back?

Comment: @IsaacMoses The answer was posted after Pesach but before Pesach Sheini.

Comment: @Daniel, he was quoting Numbers 9:7.

Answer (score 5):

Fourteen is the number of children fathered by R' Chaim Halberstam of Sanz (from several marriages), leading to such Chassidic dynasties as Bobov and Klausenburg. For a comprehensive family tree, see:

http://www.loebtree.com/halberstam.html

Answer (score 5):

Fourteen is the number of cows (7 skinny 7 fat) and sheaves (7 fat 7 lean) in Paroh's dreams.

Comment: "And fourteen are the cows in Pharaoh's dream" -- it fits the beat!

Answer (score 4):

**FOURTEEN** is the number of different people in tenach who had the name **ZECHARIAH** - **זכריה**

This is the most common name in Tanach

[note: If we consider the names **ZECHARIAH** - זכריה and **ZECHARAYAHU** - זכריהו as the same name then we have **27** people in Tanach with this name]

Comment: Can you provide a list of these different people, such as where in Tanakh they show up? Otherwise how do we know this claim is correct?

Answer (score 3):

Fourteen is "enough" (*dai*=14 in Gematria) of these questions!

Comment: If you don't like them you don't have to answer.

Comment: If you'd all just given great answers for One, it would have been enough. If you'd all just given great answers for Two, it would have been enough. ... But you gave great answers for One, Two ..., and Fourteen. As Bas613 observes, that's hardly incentive for me to stop.

Comment: Bas613, I was just kidding! We can go on to 1000, I'll still be having fun.

Answer (score 3):

Purim is on the 14th day of Adar

Answer (score 2):

Yaakov spent 14years at the academy of Eber. 
Bereshit Rabbah 68:5

Bamidbar Rabbah 18:7
Maharzu emends the Midrash where Korach mistakenly forsees 24 "watches" (1 Chronicles 6 & 25) to actually be **Fourteen**.

Answer (score 2):

- Fourteen as the 14th of Nissan, the day of bringing and slaughtering the Korban Pesach.
- Fourteen as Kedolaromer and the kings waged war on the 14th year against the others kings in Bereshit 14:5
- And also these other entries for "ארבע עשר" in Tanach:
  http://www.tora.us.fm/tnk/find.php?q=%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%A2+%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%A8

Answer (score 1):

**14** is the number of the parts in the Pesach Seder ([Order of the Seder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passover_Seder#Order_of_the_Seder))

1) Kadesh
2) Urchatz
3) Karpas
4) Yachatz
5)  Maggid
6) Rachtzah
7) Motzei Matzah
8)  Maror
9) Koreich
10) Shulchan Oreich
11)  Tzafun
12)  Bareich
13) Hallel
14) Nirtzah

Comment: I thought there are 15 steps in the Pesach Seder?

Comment: @Eli83 which is #15?

Comment: @Eli83 maybe counting Motzi Matzah as 2 instead of counting as 1?

Comment: I think I read in one Artscroll Haggadah a comment which explains that we sing the Haggadah and the 15 steps of the Haggadah as the Leviim used to sing 15 psalms of ascents at the Temple on the 15 steps while people brought korbanot.