# Chamisha Asar - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows fifteen?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. After about one business day, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: Prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/762/arbaa-asar-mi-yodeya?r=SearchResults

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/841/shisha-asar-mi-yodeya?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fifteen are the extra years added to King Chizkiyahu's lifetime, after his sincere prayer and resolution to fulfill Hashem's command to marry and bear children (II Kings 20:6 and Isaiah 38:5; Talmud, Berachos 10a).

Comment: How would you sing that?

Answer (score 10):

Fifteen are the women who [exempt their co-wives](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/h/h31.htm). (Mishna Yevamot 1:1)

(from Yibum and Chalitza)

Comment: You could sing this one to the rhythm.

Answer (score 8):

Fifteen was the depth (in cubits) of the Flood waters above the mountaintops (Gen. 7:20) - or according to R' Yehudah ([Bereishis Rabbah 32:17](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14385&st=&pgnum=75)), all over the world.

Answer (score 8):

Fifteen years old to start learning Talmud. (Avot 5:24)

Answer (score 7):

Fifteen are the steps from the *azarah* to the *ezras Kohanim*.

Answer (score 7):

Fifteen are the Shirei HaMa'alos.

Answer (score 7):

Fifteen is the date of holidays in [five](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passover#Date_in_the_spring_and_length) [of](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tu_B'Av) [the](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sukkot) [twelve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tu_Bishvat) [months](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim#Shushan_Purim).

Or, according to some, [six](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16144/matza-on-14-iyar).

And sometimes [seven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim#Purim_Katan) of thirteen.

Answer (score 7):

There are 15 Simanim at the Seder. Kadesh, Urchatz........

Answer (score 4):

Fifteen are the unintelligent people it takes to make a minyan:

Hosheea es amecha uvarech es nachalesecha urem urem urem urem venasem urem venasem ad olam

(Yes, this is a joke.)

Answer (score 3):

With Fifteen (the gematria of the name Yud-Heh) He formed the worlds.

Answer (score 3):

15 are the days S'faradim are not sad during the Omer.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/27796/759

Answer (score 3):

15 is the day of the month of Iyar that the Manna began to fall for the Jews in the desert.

Answer (score 3):

**15** - the number of instances where the Torah requires the bringing of a קרבן יחיד -- an individual sacrifice  (as listed by the **Rambam** in [Hilchos Maaseh Hakorbanos 1:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Sacrificial_Procedure.1.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

- 1) **הבכור** - **the firstborn offerings** ([Hilchos Bechoros 1:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Firstlings.1.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
- 2) **והמעשר** - **the tithe offerings** ([Hilchos Bechoros 6:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Firstlings.6.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
- 3) **והפסח** - **the Korban Pesach** ([Hilchos Korban Pesach 1:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Paschal_Offering.1.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
- 4) ו**החגיגה** והיא שלמים - **the chagigah offering**s, i.e., the peace offerings [brought in association with the pilgrimage festivals] ([Hilchos Chagigah 1:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Festival_Offering.1.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
- 5) ו**הראיה** והיא עולות - **the pilgrimage offering** which is a burnt-offering ([Hilchos Chagigah 1:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Festival_Offering.1.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
- 6) ו**קרבן הגר** והוא עולה מן הבהמה או שני בני יונה או שתי תורים ושניהן עולה או שתי בהמות אחת עולה ואחת שלמים - **the sacrifice brought by a convert**, that involves a burnt-offering from a domesticated animal, two small doves or two turtle doves; both of them are burnt-offerings, or two domesticated animals, one as a burnt-offering and one as a peace-offering ([Hilchos Mechusrei Kaparah 1:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Offerings_for_Those_with_Incomplete_Atonement.1.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
- 7) **והנודר או המתנדב עולה או שלמים** - **one who vows or pledges a burnt-offering or a peace offering** ([Hilchos Maaseh Hakorbanos 14:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Sacrificial_Procedure.14.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
- 8) ו**שלמים הבאין עם הלחם** הם הנקראים תודה - **peace-offerings that are accompanied by bread**; they are called thanksgiving offerings ([Hilchos Maaseh Hakorbanos 9:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Sacrificial_Procedure.9.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
- 9) **קרבנות הנזיר** והן עולה וחטאת ושלמים - **the sacrifices of a nazir**, which are a burnt-offering, a sin-offering, and a peace-offering ([Hilchos Nezirut 8:1-2](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Nazariteship.8.1-2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
- 10) **קרבנות מצורע** והן חטאת ואשם ועולה - **the sacrifices of a *metzora***, which are a sin-offering, and a guilt-offering, and a burnt-offering ([Hilchos Mechusrei Kaparah 4:1-2](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Offerings_for_Those_with_Incomplete_Atonement.4.1-2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
- 11) **וקרבנות זבים ויולדות** והן חטאת ועולה - **the sacrifices of a zav a zavah, and a women after childbirth**; they are a sin-offering and a burnt-offering ([Hilchos Mechusrei Kaparah 1:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Offerings_for_Those_with_Incomplete_Atonement.1.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
- 12) **וקרבן השוגג במצות לא תעשה שיש בה כרת** והוא חטאת - **the sacrifice brought by a person who inadvertently violated a negative commandment punishable by karet**; it is a sin-offering ([Hilchos Shegagos, 1st *perek*](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Offerings_for_Unintentional_Transgressions.1.1-5?lang=bi))
- 13) ואם נסתפק לו אם עשה או לא עשה אותו החוטא מביא אשם והוא הנקרא **אשם תלוי** - if a person was unsure of whether he transgressed or not, that transgressor brings a guilt-offering; it is called **a conditional guilt-offering** ([Hilchos Shegagos, 8th *perek*](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Offerings_for_Unintentional_Transgressions.8?lang=bi))
- 14) ויש עבירות שמביא עליהן אשם והוא הנקרא **אשם ודאי** - there are certain sins for which one brings a guilt-offering [to atone for their transgression]; this is called **a definite guilt-offering** ([Hilchos Shegagos, 9th *perek*](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Offerings_for_Unintentional_Transgressions.9.1-13?lang=bi))
- 15) **וכן איל העולה ופר החטאת שמקריב כהן גדול משלו ביוה"כ** הרי הן קרבן יחיד ופר זה הוא הנקרא פר יום הכפורים - similarly, **the ram brought as a burnt-offering and the bull the High Priest brings from his own resources as a sin-offering on Yom Kippur**, are individual offerings; the bull is called "the bull of Yom Kippur." ([Hilchos Avodas Yom HaKippurim 4:1-2](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Service_on_the_Day_of_Atonement.4.1-2?lang=bi) )

Answer (score 1):

Chamisha Asar B'Omer always comes out on Rosh Chodesh

Comment: ...as does Shisha Asar.

Comment: Put it in as an answer at Shisha Asar.

Comment: @Alex, not once we have _kidush hachodesh_, _bb"a_.

Comment: @msh ... *al pi eidim* ...

Answer (score 1):

Fifteen is the fifteen expressions in the berachah of Ha-Tov ve-ha-Meitiv (לחן ולחסד ולרחמים ולרוח הצלה והצלחה ברכה וישועה נחמה פרנסה וכלכלה ורחמים וחיים ושלום וכל טוב), which correspond to:

1. the fifteen meals of the week (2 each day and 3 on Shabbos);
2. the fifteen words in the pasuk קדושים תהיו;
3. the fifteen appearances of the word שירה in Chamishah Chumshei Torah;
4. the fifteen appearances of the word שמחה in Chamishah Chumshei Torah;
5. the fifteen names of God in the Aseret Ha-Dibrot;
6. the fifteen names of God in Va-Yosha and Az Yashir;
7. the fifteen words of Birkat Kohanim;
8. the fifteen times the root למד appears in Devarim;
9. the fifteen years required for Talmud study;
10. the fifteen times the word Kavod appears in Yechezkel;
11. the fifteen mizmorim in Tehillim following the order of the alef beis;
12. the fifteen praises in the pasuk לך ה' הגדולה;
13. the fifteen praises for the Torah in the mizmor תורת ה' תמימה;
14. the fifteen שיר המעלות;
15. the fifteen years that the three Avot overlapped in this world.

Source: [פירוש ברכת המזון למוהר"ן שפירא.](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47949&st=&pgnum=66&hilite=)

Answer (score 0):

Shemos 27:14  The hangings of one side of the gate shall be **fifteen** cubits: their pillars three, and their sockets three.

Shemot 27:15  And on the other side shall be hangings **fifteen** cubits: their pillars three, and their sockets three.

Vayikra 27:7 And if it be from sixty years old and above; if it be a male, then thy estimation shall be **fifteen** shekels, and for the female ten shekels.

Hoshea 3:2  So I bought her to me for **fifteen** silver, and an omer of barley, and a half omer of barley:

Yeshayahu 38:5  Go, and say to Hezekiah, Thus saith HaShem, the God of David thy father, I have heard thy prayer, I have seen thy tears: behold, I will add unto thy days **fifteen** years.

Answer (score 0):

1- Fifteen generations from Abraham to King Solomon; then fifteen generations from Solomon until the destruction of the Beit HaMikdash.

2- There were fifteen who ruled Israel as judges

Comment: The Shengold Jewish Encyclopedia. NY: Shengold, 1998. That's the only source I could find for the fifteen judges.

Answer (score 0):

[Midrash Rabbah - Bereishis 97] The tribes are enumerated **fifteen** times in the Torah [together].

Answer (score 0):

Shemot 25  [**Fifteen** things were given as donations toward the construction of the Mishkan:] [3] ...gold, and silver, and brass, [4]  And blue, and purple, and scarlet, and fine linen, and goats’ hair, [5]  And rams’ skins dyed red, and badgers’ skins, and shittim wood, [6]  Oil for the light, spices for anointing oil, and for sweet incense, 7  Onyx stones, and stones to be set in the ephod, and in the breastplate.