# Shisha Asar - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows sixteen?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. After about one business day, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: Prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/808/chamisha-asar-mi-yodeya?r=SearchResults

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/934/shiva-asar-mi-yodeya?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 5, accepted):

16 maneh is the [weight of mor, k'tzi'ah, shibolet neird, and kharkom](http://bible.ort.org/books/pentd2.asp?ACTION=displaypage&BOOK=2&CHAPTER=30#C1810) in the incense

Answer (score 8):

Sixteen are the cases when a co-wife is exempt from chalitzah or yibbum, according to Levi (Yevamos 10b) - he adds one case to the [fifteen mentioned in the Mishnah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/808/chamisha-asar-mi-yodeya/834#834) (ibid. 2a).

Answer (score 7):

Sixteen is the width of a [street](http://www.torah.org/learning/halacha/classes/class448.html).

Answer (score 4):

On Pesach we spill out a bit of the Kos by the Seder 16 times. 10 Makos. 3 times by Dam V'Aish Vsimros Ashan. 3 times by Detzach Adash B'Achav. [(Orach Chaim 473 - Rama)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49627&st=&pgnum=171)

Comment: I see no such custom mentioned in OC 475 in the Shulchan Aruch or the Mappah

Answer (score 3):

Uziah (king of Judah) was sixteen years old when he started to rule. (Chronicles II: 26)

Answer (score 3):

Taz(=16) is the son-in-law of the Bach(=10).

Answer (score 1):

16 is the day in *Nissan* on which the *karban omer* was brought.

Answer (score 0):

Sixteen are the categories of items that the Jews in the desert brought for the building of the Mishkan.

Comment: Where do you see this?

Comment: @DoubleAA Had you asked me 2 years ago I might remember. I have no recollection.

Comment: I always thought there were 39 things they built http://thetorah.com/the-textual-source-39-melachot-shabbat/

Comment: I didn't say they built 16 things. I said they brought 16 different types of materials for the building.

Answer (score 0):

Rachel conceived 16 months after the incident of the dudaim in the 5th year of Leah's marriage. - Sechel Tov, Bereshis 30:21