# Shemona Asar - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows eighteen?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. After about one business day, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: Prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/934/shiva-asar-mi-yodeya?r=SearchResults

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1073/tisha-asar-mi-yodeya?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eighteen are the years before one gets hitched. (Ben Shemonah Esrei LiChupah: [Avos 5:21](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%94_%D7%9B%D7%90))

Comment: Does? Should? May?

Comment: I heard the Biblical hint for this is that "Adam" appears 18 times before the first use of "Ish"

Comment: Another one is that the verse about who the Kohen Gadol may marry (Lev. 21:13) starts with the word והוא, whose numerical value is 18 (Baal Haturim on this verse).

Comment: Isaac. it is too complicated to get into and besides, none of those words fit the meter of the tune!

Comment: Checkmark due to value added by interesting comments.

Comment: I heard the Biblical hint for this is that "Adam" appears 18 times before the first use of "Ish"
- Shalom Correct. [The word,] man is written eighteen times in Parshat Bereshit (the beginning of Genesis) from, "And God said, 'let us make man'" (Genesis 1:26), until "And the Lord God built the side" (Genesis 2:22, when Eve was created). One [use of the word, man] is for itself [such that] eighteen remain to be expounded [in this way]. - Bartenura on Pirkei Avot 5:21. Although one may only count sixteen, see Ikar Tosafot Yom Tov on Pirkei Avot 5:21.

Answer (score 6):

Shemona Asar was the number of berachot in the Shemona Esrei, before the addition of Birkas HaMinim." ([Berachot 28b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=28b&format=pdf))

Comment: Corresponding to the 18 mentions of _Hashem's_ name in Psalm 29 and the _Shema._ https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.28b.17

Answer (score 6):

Eighteen are the minimum (or according to Rambam, the absolute) number of days in a woman's cycle, according to the original Torah law: seven of niddah (Lev. 15:19), and eleven of zivah (based either on Lev. 15:25, or an unwritten *halachah le-Moshe mi-Sinai* - Talmud, [Niddah 72b](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=5406&size=1)-[73a](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=5407&size=1)).

Answer (score 5):

Eighteen is the value (in maneh) of the linen clothing that the Kohen Gadol wore for his first entry into the Holy of Holies each Yom Kippur, according to the majority opinion ([Yoma 34b](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=992&size=1)).

Answer (score 3):

There are eighteen sins for which the punishment is *misa bide shamayim* but for which one can get lashes. Source: [*Rambam*, *Sanhedrin* 19](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/e119n.htm).

Answer (score 3):

18 are the instances of prayer in the Torah, as enumerated by Rav Saadya Gaon in [the introduction to his Siddur](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20685&st=&pgnum=60): Gen 20:17, 25:21, 32:10, Exo 8:8, 8:26, 9:33, 10:18, 15:1, 32:11, 33:13, 34:9, Num 11:2, 12:13, 14:13, 21:7, 21:17, 27:16, Deu 3:23.

He also mentions that there are 18 days the Torah sanctified as Moadim: 7 for Pesach, 1 each for Shavuot, Rosh haShana, and Yom Kippurim, and 8 for Sukkot.

Answer (score 3):

18 things were enacted at this day (Mishna Shabbat 1,  4)

> וְאֵלּוּ מִן הַהֲלָכוֹת שֶׁאָמְרוּ בַעֲלִיַּת חֲנַנְיָה בֶן חִזְקִיָּה בֶן גֻּרְיוֹן כְּשֶׁעָלוּ לְבַקְּרוֹ. נִמְנוּ וְרַבּוּ בֵּית שַׁמַּאי עַל בֵּית הִלֵּל, **וּשְׁמֹנָה עָשָׂר דְּבָרִים גָּזְרוּ בוֹ בַיּוֹם**: ‏

Answer (score 2):

There are 18 perakim in maseches Oholos.

Answer (score 2):

Eighteen are the rows of R. Elazar Ben Azaria's beard that turned white.

([Berachot 28a](https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=28&format=pdf))

Answer (score 1):

Lag B'Omer is on 18 Iyur

Comment: Only in our fixed calendar (or in the variable calendar if Nisan happened to have 30 days).

Answer (score 1):

Eighteen is the age at which one should finish learning the entire Talmud according to one opinion (15 to start learning (Pirkei Avos), and it is a machlokes (in kiddushin I think) if it takes 3 or 5 years to complete it).

Comment: Sourcing that machloket in kiddushin would be valuable. (Even better would be to show that the opinions in kiddushin had ever seen the pseudo-mishna in avot about ages.)

Comment: @DoubleAA pseudo-mishna?

Comment: @Asher it's one of those braysas that often gets printed after Avot (there's some after bikkurim too)

Comment: @DoubleAA That's the 6th perek while this is the end of the 5th perek. i guess it could depend if the yehi ratzon is before or after this mishna-i think the gra puts it after the perek

Comment: @Asher the fact is in all the old manuscripts of mishna, Avot ends before this.

Answer (score 1):

18 [*tefachim*] was the [height of the Menora](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/89341/how-large-was-the-menorah).

([Menachot 28b](https://www.sefaria.org/Menachot.28b.46-48?lang=bi))

Answer (score 1):

Sichon's (the King of the Emorites) thigh bones were eighteen cubits long
([Midrash Tanchuma, Buber ed., Devarim appendix 7](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma_Buber%2C_Appendix_to_Devarim.7.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

Answer (score 0):

18 is the gematriya of chai

Comment: Also of "Yach".

Comment: Also of חטא.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​