# Tish'a Asar - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows nineteen?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. After about one business day, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: Prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1014/shemona-asar-mi-yodeya?r=SearchResults

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1104/esrim-mi-yodeya?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nineteen are the years in a "machzor katan" - the cycle of regular and leap years in the Jewish calendar.

Answer (score 6):

Nineteen are the *[Letters](http://www.judaism.com/display.asp?etn=BJGAH)* of R' Hirsch.

Answer (score 4):

19 are the berachot in the 18

Answer (score 3):

Nineteen were the centuries between [Destruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Temple_of_Jerusalem#Destruction) and [Re-unification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temple_Mount#Post-1967).

Answer (score 3):

Nineteen days is the longest possible *tzara'at*-quarantine. (Nega'im 3:8)

Comment: Coronavirus quarantines are only 14 days...

Answer (score 2):

Nineteen are the books of Tanach that the Christians agree count as a single book each.

(Of the 24 books of the Tanach, Christians split each of Samuel, Kings, Chronicles, Ezra/Nechemiah, and Trei Asar into two or more books.  That leaves nineteen.  5 of the Chumash + 5 Megilos + Yehoshua Shoftim Yishaya Yirmiya Yechzkel + Tehilim Mishlei Iyov + Daniel = 19. )

Answer (score 2):

19 were the years that Am Israel dwelled in Kadesh, and nineteen years they were wandering about aimlessly (see [Rashi in Devarim 1:46](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_46184_36.pdf))

Answer (score 1):

19 is the day of Kislev when R' Shneur Zalman of Liadi was released from prison.