# Echad Ve'esrim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows twenty-one?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. After about one business day, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: Should this be "Esrim Ve-echad" or "Echad Ve'esrim"?

Comment: I think you're correct.  I think if the number is just 20-something, the 20 goes first.  See Numbers 7:88,  עֶשְׂרִים וְאַרְבָּעָה פָּרִים .

Comment: Echad Ve'esrim. Even in our numbers 21 was originally read as "one and twenty"- After all, our numbers are Arabic and Arabic reads from right to left.

Comment: Oops I just gave away my answer for "24."  (And it doesn't involve Jack Bauer.)

Comment: And take a look at yesterday's sefira count in any siddur - "Echad Ve'esrim Yom ...".

Comment: Argh but Exodus 38:24 is תשע ועשרים ככר .  So it's "nine-and-twenty talent" (note the singular), but "twenty-four bulls."  Is that a gender thing?  Or do we put a pure number (uninflected) before monetary sums?  This is a job for a real grammarian.

Comment: "x-and-twenty" is also the preferred language for the date in a Kesubah.  But for both Kesubah and sefirah, it's a pure number, "one-and-twenty day" (not "days"); vs "twenty-and-four bulls."

Comment: Yahu: not necessarily. It is true that in Sefiras Haomer we use the form "units+tens," but Magen Avraham 489:5 comments that really it should follow the form used in the local vernacular (he also cites Yoma 55a in this regard, where there is a similar discussion about how the Kohen Gadol counts the sprinklings on Yom Kippur). In Yiddish the units are indeed placed first, and that is probably why indeed our siddurim have it in this form; but after all, in English we put the tens first.

Comment: Shalom, true. We need to do a bit more research, but for our purposes we are talking about the question "# mi yodeya" and until you assign it to something it is a pure number.

Comment: Alex, 1. Look in the Sefaradi siddurim, it puts the units first as well. In English we only started putting the tens first because we read the Arabic symbols in the wrong direction. In Middle-English the term "four and twenty (blackbirds baked in a pie)" was used.

Comment: Not that the rhyme is a proof since it could have been said that way to fit the meter, but there are other examples and that is the first that came to mind (Girsah DiYankusah!)

Comment: Shalom: Even with pure numbers, not necessarily. We find חמש וששים שנה (Gen. 5:21,23) and חמשה וששים... שקל (Num. 3:50), but ששים וחמש שנה (Is. 7:8). – Alex 0 secs ago

Comment: Shalom, Alex, Me: Arghhhh! We need to speak to real biblical grammarian who also is at least a Yodeya Sefer.

Comment: Yahu: the Ashkenazi vs. Sefaradi difference is probably indeed because of the local difference in the vernacular; in Spanish, after all, you say "veintiuno." As to English - if the change from "four-and-twenty" to "twenty-four" is because of how we read the Arabic symbols, then how come, for example, German - which uses them too - puts the units first?

Comment: Here's a relevant citation: http://books.google.com/books?id=jZlwYGilLW0C&lpg=PP1&ots=_zkIAAb7qh&dq=%22introduction%20to%20biblical%20hebrew%20syntax%22&pg=PA280#v=onepage&q&f=false and subsequent pages. Apparently both forms are pretty common throughout Tanach.

Comment: ... and when I posted my original comment, I wasn't sure if anyone would notice it! The context I'm interested in is what form the back pages of the Hagada would have used.

Comment: Alex, the Sefardim put the unit first just like the Ashkenazim.

Comment: "The numerals are arranged with their lowest value digit to the right, with higher value positions added to the left. This arrangement was adopted identically into the numerals as used in Europe. Languages written in the Latin alphabet run from left to right, unlike languages written in the Arabic alphabet. Hence, from the point of view of the reader, numerals in Western texts are written with the highest power of the base first whereas numerals in Arabic texts are written with the lowest power of the base first." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals

Comment: OK, so it seems that Biblically, we could go either way. I skimmed through the Hagada, and could only find one on-point example: R' Akiva's position that the Egyptians were smitten on the sea with "fifty and two hundred" blows. Unless someone convinces me otherwise by then, when I go to the next number later today, I'll switch to little-endian form.

Comment: Isaac, one last point (which might clinch it?) : Our gematria numerology system that we seem to have used for quite some time puts the highest power base first. Hence: "Chaf Alef Mi Yodeya?" Seems to read as "Esrim V'ehad".

Comment: As Shalom says in the comments below, "עבר יומו בטל קרבנו." I'm going to stick with litte-endian.

Comment: Avar "Yomo". Tomorrow is another day, so why not change it? :-)

Comment: Some (non-Jewish) Bible scholars have suggested that "twenty-and-one" means "plus or minus, but that's the ballpark", as the focus is on the bigger number. "One-and-twenty" indicates more precision. Interesting idea, not one I'd say is especially contrary to our mesorah.

Comment: Just heard R' Hershel Schachter endorse changing Sefirah to "twenty-and-one" as we no longer speak Yiddish (and yes he referenced the blackbirds). He said "one-and-twenty" is more prevalent in Chumash, but "twenty-and-one" wins out in Nach -- reflecting a shift in Hebrew over time. Fascinating. (Just using 21 as an example.)

Comment: @Shalom You mean that tonight RHS really said "Hayom Shloshim uShenayim yom shehem..."??

Comment: Prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1104/esrim-mi-yodeya?r=SearchResults

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1140/shnayim-veesrim-mi-yodeya?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Twenty-one are the books of Tanach that use the "normal" system of trop (cantillation).

(Actually, 21 and a fraction, since the first 36 and the last 11 verses of Iyov - the framing narrative - use it too.)

Comment: The other books with the different system being Psalms and Proverbs.  Together with Job, they're known as ספרי אמ״ת.

Comment: In my yeshivah days, the joke went:

Q. What do Tehillim, Mishlei, and Iyov have in common?

A. In Tehillim, it's often difficult to see the connection between one chapter and the next. In Mishlei, it's often difficult to see the connection between one verse and the next. In Iyov, it's often difficult to see the connection between one word and the next!

Comment: That must have been some Yeshiva, if students were familiar with Tehilim as a book or with Mishlei or Iyov at all. Gush?

Comment: Nope, Oholei Torah (in Brooklyn). There were boys there who knew their way around Tanach pretty well.

Answer (score 6):

Twenty-one are the days when we recite the complete Hallel (outside of Israel): the first two days of Pesach (and according to some customs, also the first two nights), two days of Shavuos, nine of Sukkos/Shemini Atzeres/Simchas Torah, and eight of Chanukah. (Erachin 10a)

Comment: Some will say "Hey?! What about Hei Iyaar?!" ;-))

Comment: OK, then, "twenty-one are the days when we recite the complete Hallel *with a berachah*" - see http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/1047/is-yom-haatzmout-a-chag/1054#1054 .

Comment: That formulation is still not ledivrei hakol, but what Halachic statement ever is?

Comment: Followup question: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/64267

Answer (score 5):

21 are the  days between the seventeenth of Tammuz and the ninth of Av.

Comment: What do you mean by between? There are 22 days inclusive and 20 exclusive

Answer (score 5):

There are twenty-one sins for which one can get *kares* or lashes, but not court-imposed death. Source: [*Rambam*, *Sanhedrin* 19](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/e119n.htm).

Answer (score 3):

Twenty-one is the Gematria of "ach", which serves to diminish.  When it says the Flood left "ach Noach", the diminution combined with the onomatopoeia indicate that Noah was retching blood.  (Yuck!)

Comment: Rashi on Bereishit 7:23.

Answer (score 3):

Twenty-one is the age below which the Rambam recommend medically against drinking alcohol.

(Better late than never?)

Comment: Give us a link or at least the source please!

Comment: I'm afraid I saw it in an English language compilation many years ago, but it stood out because of the significance of 21 in US law. It is probably in the Mishneh Torah and I intend on trying to locate it. Just to be clear, I don't think it was meant as an issur which would proscribe any drinking by those under the age of 21, and I'm not sure that by contemporary standards 21 has any particular medical significance.

Comment: It could be in one of Rambam's medical treatises which by the way are available in English.

Comment: Codified by the Kitzur SA 32:18.

Answer (score 3):

The letters engraved into the luchot cut through from one side to the other. The holes in the center of the letters Mem and Samech (ם & ס) were held up by a miracle. This occurs 21 times on each side of the luchot (& only in the first five commandments). (Parshat Va'etchanan)

[related](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/12948/702)

Answer (score 1):

21 are the days of dealing with tzara'as (in most cases).

Comment: This isn't true. No Hesger lasts that long. I recommend deletion.

Comment: @DoubleAA the answer doesn't say _hesger_. If you can clarify it, that's what the [edit] button is for.

Comment: @msh I don't know of any way this answer is right that editing would help

Comment: Shalom, why haven't you deleted this?

Answer (score 1):

21 is the number of times the word ברית or some variation thereof appears in sefer Tehillim (You can count yourself [here](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t0.htm), make sure not to count repeat results)

Comment: Why is this significant?

Comment: @DoubleAA I could give you a lengthy explanation, but why is it less significant than the number of holes in the luchos that were held up?  Or this -http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1143/4794

Comment: @Yez if you can provide an explanation of any length, doing so would make this answer more valuable.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I'll make you a deal. You explain to me why the linked answer has 8 upvotes and no complaints while this one has zero upvotes and two complaints and I will inconvenience myself to write up the meaning of it. And if the answer is because that one quotes a medrash, that doesn't show me _anything_ about why it is significant.

Comment: @Yez [Here, have some points.](https://youtu.be/v38lu0Bi0Kk) If you have worthwhile or interesting information relevant to this answer, I request that you add it, so as to enrich the Internet, which is why we're here.

Answer (score 1):

21 are the verses in [Ovadiah](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t16.htm).​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: [With English](http://www.sefaria.org/Obadiah.1.1?lang=bi). Notably, this is the shortest book in Tanach.

Answer (score 0):

21 is the public drinking age (in the U.S. http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/23/158.html ) and this is enforced by all states with many making exceptions for under 21 drinking in private settings, small groups, parental permission and for **sacramental** (*kiddush, havadalah, bris milah,* etc.) purposes.