# Torah Format of Haazinu

Tags: torah-reading, haazinu

What is the symbolism behind the mesorah to write the song of Haazinu in the two-halves of the klaf as seen [here](https://hardcoremesorah.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/haazinu.jpg) and below? (*Why* is this style the standard song format?) 
[image]

Comment: That's just the standard song format in all of Tanakh. Only Shirat HaYam and Shirat Devorah have an unusual special format.

Comment: Looks like a dupe of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/95500/5275. I cannot vote to close based on it, as it has no votes or answers, yet.

Comment: @DanF Great catch, you're right. I didn't find that one when I was looking through the questions before positing this one. I guess I'll keep it open for a little with the hopes of the shorter question than the other garnering a response.

Comment: I don't understand what the scan of the Gutnick Chumash brings to light