# Leining Tehillim

Tags: ashkenazi, tehilim-psalms, mesorah-tradition, trop-cantillation

I would just like to know - is there a mesorah for Tehillim trop for Ashkenazim? I know that there is a Sefaradi one (I have heard them) but I would like to know if there is any Askenazi one. Thank you.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/30702/759

Comment: Idelsohn recorded some bits and pieces, see for example this South German tradition on [p. 163](http://sammlungen.ub.uni-frankfurt.de/freimann/content/titleinfo/8595318).

Answer (score 3):

There was an *Ashkenazi Tehillim trop mesorah*, but it was lost about half a century ago:

R' Yisroel Rabinovich of Monsey, NY, is a master *baal koreh* and *baal dikduk*. He told me that as a young *Yerushalmi* boy, he met the last living man who knew the *Ashkenazi* cantillations for *Tehillim*. Unfortunately, at the time, neither R' Rabinovich, nor anyone else around, was interested enough in *kriah* to take note of this *mesorah*.

Comment: I wonder if he meant something like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4VjG6wLBVwQ

Comment: @DoubleAA "נוסח תהילים שילדים נוהגים לומר" and it doesn't seem to follow the written trop.

Answer (score 2):

There is an ashkenazi trop for Tehillim, Mishlei, and Iyov (טעמי אמ"ת) but it was reconstructed from the Sephardic tradition. KAJ in Washington Heights chants Tehillim 29 with that trop on Friday nights. You can buy software to learn Ta'amei emet, and find sample mp3s from the software [here](http://www.kinnor.com/Taamei_Emet/).

Comment: That recording is the same as in [the link I posted in a comment under the question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/30702/759). It is a reconstructed trop, not original.

Comment: @DoubleAA If it was reconstructed then it *should* be the same as the original -- in an ideal world, anyway. Was it reconstructed or merely constructed?

Comment: @msh210 Attempted reconstruction? As I understand it, it was made by listening to the recordings of three different Syrians reading the Tehillim and kind of mixing it up together. Something like that.

Comment: @DoubleAA, ah, so a _m'kubal/nimsar_ one (at least pretty much), but not Ashkenazically.

Comment: So it isn't Authentic Ashkenazus then but I would argue that if that's what's used by contemporary Ashkenazim to lein tehillim, it is now the Ashkenazic trop. I will edit to include that information

Comment: @Yitzchak Are you basing yourself on my comments or do you have your own knowledge of this?

Comment: Just from your comment

Comment: In the recordings (track 2 @8:40) R' Perlman says that his trop was chosen from one of 3 recordings that R' Zilberman felt to be most accurate in terms of Dikduk, and varied naturally as it continued to be used by Ashkenazim.