# End note in ספרי אמ״ת

Tags: tehilim-psalms, trop-cantillation

I asked [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/89339/is-there-an-ashkenazic-mesorah-for-mishlei-and-tehillem-trop) and was answered [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/36852/16706) that there exists free means on the internet to learn the *trup* of Tehilim, siferei emes.

Someone even linked a YouTube video of a [kid reading with the trup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xBLGSq6Sfio).

However, while learning the material, and also evident in the [video,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xBLGSq6Sfio) there seems to not be present an equivalent of the ‘special end note’ that exists by Torah readings and Haftorah readings. (Meaning at the end of an Aliyah or the end of the haftorah)

I am looking for the answer, on good authority, whether or not it does or does not exist in this trup. As I understand it, when people read navi with trup, they would end the perek with the same note as one ends a haftorah. And therefore, when reading a chapter of teheilim for example, there would be an equevlent.

Comment: "As I understand it, when people read navi with trup, they would end the perek with the same note as one ends a haftorah" that's not true... there is absolutely zero Halakhic relevance to the Perek endings (which are Christian in origin). You can give a finale note when you finish any relevant section if you want, but there's no reason a priori to think a Christian chapter break should be relevant. The whole notion of finale notes is not actually a Halakhic requirement of leining. It's just a flourish to let the community know you're done.

Comment: See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26129/759

Comment: Fair point, however there is endings for Haftorah endings, so still would there be any type of equivalent.

Comment: After this clarification, does the question still stand? If it wasn’t mentioned [in the lessons], does that mean it doesn’t exist.. or was it in the original sefardi version..

Comment: You should also note that not all traditions have an ending motive.

Comment: @kazi bácsi I didn’t know that

Comment: Italians say (and I see that some others as well) גאלנו יהוה צבאות שמו קדוש ישראל, and then they continue with the haftarah blessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Based on some of the comments, what I concluded from them, and didn’t previously understand:*

We have a tradition of *trup*.

There are different notes used throughout any given verse.

One of these notes is an ‘end note’ which is used on every verse in Tanach.

Now, whether or not people sometimes will or will not end either a Haftorah, Aliyah, Megillah Chapter, etc. on a particlar note is quite irrelevant of our tradition.

And so, although I *do not* have it on good authority that there is or is not an end note for טעמי אמ״ת, it is quite irrelevant in practice. (There probably is one, though)

For reference: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sof_passuk