# Looking for an interpretation of Shir Hashirim that follows the parsha breaks

Tags: product-recommendation, commentaries, mesorah-tradition, shir-hashirim

Coming off of some tangential discussion in the comments [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/91920/end-note-in-%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99-%D7%90%D7%9E-%D7%AA?noredirect=1#comment298813_91920), I'm looking for an interpretation of Shir Hashirim that follows the parsha breaks.  It doesn't have to explicitly address every one, but it should use them as a framework in deciding the logical units of the sefer.

Ideally, I'd love a Malbim-style commentary that gives the mashal and nimshal side by side and correlates details between them, but that's not a deal breaker.  Pshat only or Rashi style is fine too.

DoubleAA mentioned that there are multiple traditions for the parsha breaks.  I don't know how much they differ.  For the purpose of this question, the more authoritative (e.g. Aleppo) the better, but I'll accept interpretations based on any parsha breaks that come from an actual mesorah.  Basically, anything short of "here's my pshat and I'll make up parsha breaks to match it" counts.

Does anything like this exist?

Comment: Yes, the Minchas Shai and similar commentaries probably list the parsha breaks.  No, I won't accept that as an answer.  That's cheating.

Comment: So what’s wrong with the the existing Malbim commentary (שירי הנפש, מליצה)?

Comment: @Shmuel I like it very much, but it doesn't follow the parsha breaks.  That's what I'm looking for here.  I forget which, but at least one of his divisions is in the middle of a parsha, and some of his logical breaks within the sections are as well.