# Has anyone "composed" music for the trope for Tehilim, Mishle and Iyov?

Tags: trop-cantillation, tehilim-psalms

The 3 books Mishlei, Iyov and Tehillim has some unusual trope notes that we do not see in any other book of Tanac"h. E.g. - Yetiv or munach on top of a word. See [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=50393&st=&pgnum=12&hilite=) for example.

We know how to sing the trope for the other Sefarim. Has anyone composed / standardized or formulated a way to sing these unusual notes in these 3 books?

Comment: That's not a Munach. It's an Ilui.

Comment: Dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1129/759

Comment: @DoubleAA - wow! I never heard of that note. Any place that mentions the names of these notes?

Comment: Any work on Taamei Emet will discuss it.

Comment: Yes, it is a dupe. Thanks for the link to the other Q. One of the comments has a link to what may be a trope sample.