# Why no music and singing during daily prayer?

Tags: shacharis-morning-prayer, music

Throughout the (morning) prayers a large amount of passages speak about praising and singing to the Lord.

> "Shiru lo, zamru lo..."
>
> "Nihalelicha... Bishvachos Uvizimiros..."
>
> "...bo'u lifonov birnana".

Why is there not more singing and music instituted in daily prayer? In the Temple prayers were sung with a full orchestra.

I saw somewhere that said that Rabbi Akiva Eiger said we should not have music during praying because then it's similar to non-jewish ritual praying services.

So we refrain from the very important concept of praising God because other religions also praise their God??

Perhaps, because everyone is busy rushing to work in the morning, there's no time. I that case shouldn't the rabbis have instituted at least once a month a musical gathering to sing praises to God?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. There are plenty of minyanim who _do_ sing the tefillos. Usually this is only done on Shabbos and Yom Tov, though, when people aren't in a rush to get to work. Have you never been to a minyan that sings?

Comment: @ezra i don't know any orthodox congregations that have music during prayers. singing yes. though not so much.

Comment: As @ezra said, often the only times people have time to sing is Shabbos and Yom Tov, when you _can't_ use musical instruments.  I've occasionally heard of, but never seen, people using musical instruments on Chol Hamoed.

Comment: @Heshy added this to question: Because everyone is busy rushing to work in the morning, shouldn't the rabbis have instituted at least once a month a musical gathering to sing praises to God?

Comment: They did.  Hallel on Rosh Chodesh.

Comment: @Heshy you have musical instruments with your congregation in rosh chodesh praying?

Comment: I attended a Sephardic shul in Great Neck NY that had tambourines and some other basic percussion instruments laying around so that you could play and sing during Davening. Yes it was a fully orthodox shul. Whatever the Sephardi version of yeshivish is.

Comment: https://www.koltorah.org/halachah/music-and-matzeivah-by-rabbi-chaim-jachter

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/52759/170

Answer (score 3):

Some congregations *do* sing on weekdays, particularly during *p'sukei d'zimrah*.  But the melodies are more "basic" than those used on Shabbat.  I once asked a rabbi about the musical differences (why not sing the nicer melodies every day?) and he said it's because we should elevate Shabbat.  I can't cite a source for that (the rabbi I asked has moved away), but it's consistent with other things that we do to elevate Shabbat, like wearing our finest clothes and making more elaborate meals.

An additional, practical matter is that, as you said in the question, for weekday morning *minyanim*, at least some of the attendees have to get to work after.  On Shabbat, on the other hand, where else do we have to be?

Note that when we add Hallel on a weekday (Rosh Chodesh, Chol HaMoed, Chanukah), many (most?) congregations do add singing there.

As for musical instruments, the Levites did play instruments during the temple service, and [Arakhin 11a](https://www.sefaria.org/Arakhin.11a?lang=bi) and [Sukkah 50b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.50b.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) record a disagreement about whether the essence of music is the song (from the mouth) or the instruments, with the majority saying the latter.  That is, instruments are secondary (and some say they were played by slaves, not Levites), while the song is essential.  Since the destruction of the second temple, the rabbis [forbade instrumental music in services](https://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/synagogue-religious-music/), both as a sign of mourning for the temple and in response to Hellenistic influences.

Comment: Did they use musical instruments in the temple on the Sabbath?

Comment: I would think we can't have musical instruments because of morning the destruction of the Temple. See Shulchan Aruch OC 560:3. There certainly is what to discuss here (would this be considered a mitzva need), but perhaps this is why instrumental music was not institutionalized.

Comment: @larry909, the Gemara discusses that, Succa 50b.

Comment: Thanks @Mordechai; I've updated this answer.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Arachin 11a might be a better source than Sukkah, as it deals with this issue more extensively.

Comment: Thanks @DonielF! I agree; that's better because it goes into more detail.