# How many taamim/cantillation/trop marks are there?

Tags: hebrew, language, trop-cantillation

I know there are different nusachot, but is there a maximal amount?

Comment: How do you want to count? By name? By shape? By tune? For all 24 books of Tanach?

Comment: How about all of them?

Comment: Did you find something lacking in the lists on the web, like at Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_cantillation#Names_and_shapes_of_the_te'amim I don't want to require someone to just copy those here, but if you can explain what exactly you aren't sure about or what your motivation for asking is, someone is more likely to get you a original helpful response.

Comment: So per Rabbi Wikipedia, the answer is thirty two?

Comment: If you say so (I haven't checked). There's bound to be different ways of counting things but without any guidance from you that's as good an answer as any.

Comment: Also, Sifrei Eme"s (Iyov, Mishlei and Tehillim) have a different cantillation system than the rest of Tanakh. I think Yemenites have the only active tradition of how the to sing them.

Comment: @MichaBerger https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1580/759

Answer (score 3):

Is this chart from the latest Koren Tanakh helpful?

[image]

Comment: I don't see how it's more helpful than wikipedia. Arguably less so in fact. It doesn't list all four kinds of munach (wikipedia at least lists 2) nor does it list maalya, sachfa, 'metiga', though it does list yored separate from merkha, distinguishes 3 of the 4 reviim in Emet (wp doesn't at all), and doesn't bother with the 'double pashta'. Don't get me wrong, neither list is terrible.

Comment: @DoubleAA What are the "4 reviim in Emet"? I know the three listed above.

Comment: @magicker revia gadol revia katan and revia mugrash are three. The fourth is the revia that comes at the end of verses instead of an etnachta when the stitch after the etnachta would be too short like in the last verse in Psalms. Some call it the oxymoronic revia mugrash bli geresh רמב"ג but R Breuer maintained that classically it was called just revia plain without a modifier. AFAICT he's right but it's really unhelpful for clear discussion so I'll often call it the "simple revia" or "final revia" or something like that.

Comment: @DoubleAA I understood (following Wickes) that these were just a revia mugrash (Wickes adds in the geresh, AFAICT). I guess that understanding is outdated?

Comment: @magicker R Breuer has a couple of pages about this where he writes that was something people did in the face of a bunch of inconsistently printed texts to "fix" them. The old manuscripts though are very consistent when they have the geresh and when they don't. Additionally the meshartim for each are different.

Comment: @magicker moreover compare Mishlei 1:1 how the old manuscripts don't bother with the revia when the 'mugrash' is anyway on the accented letter (ie mileil), but you don't see that in the last verse in Psalms.

Comment: @DoubleAA Thanks. I see some cases (eg. Ps 116:9, 135:21) that the meshartim are different, but in other cases (the majority?) they do match (eg. Ps 31:3, 55:23). Wickes does note (p76, top) that some manuscripts do indeed mark revia mugrash at these spots. I need to see R Breuer inside at some point (long been on my to-do list).

Comment: @magicker I can never keep the meshartim rules in EMT straight, but apparently the general two-meshartim form for revia mugrash is merkha-merkha but for plain revia it's tarcha-merkha. Apparently also if there's a single mesharet smushed between a revia gadol and a plain revia it switches sometimes to mahpakh-metzunnar. I haven't checked all the examples. Compare חֶלְקִ֖י יְהֹוָ֥ה אָמַ֗רְתִּי לִשְׁמֹ֥ר דְּבָרֶֽיךָ and דִּשַּׁ֥נְתָּ בַשֶּׁ֥מֶן רֹ֝אשִׁ֗י כּוֹסִ֥י רְוָיָֽה

Comment: Is that the new translation? It hasn't been published yet, has it? Advance copy?

Comment: @DoubleAA Ha, another Wickes-ism. He calls mercha-mercha a Ben Naphtali phenomenon, whereas he says tarcha-mercha is Ben Asher's, and "fixes" accordingly.

Comment: @IsaacMoses yes exactly right, it is coming in 2-3 months

Answer (score 0):

[image: tabula accentuum]
So DoubleAA, you said there are four types of munach? What else is missing?