# How are the trope / taamim of Sifrei Emeth Sung?

Tags: tanach, tehilim-psalms, trop-cantillation

Some books in Tanach have a different kind of trop for the words. (see [Psalms](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.1?lang=bi), e.g. under בַּעֲצַ֢ת and above רְשָׁ֫עִ֥ים)

How is this trop read/sung?

[Related](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1129/22323)

Comment: @aaron that issue is covered extensively in the related question.

Comment: @DoubleAA but the question itself hasn't been asked. Do we base duplicates off of questions or off of answers?

Comment: @Aaron Apparently, "Are they read to a tune... Have they ever been read publicly with the tune?" was interpreted to contain an implicit "and if so what is it?" If you'd like to edit there to clarify/[generalize](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1299/759), be my guest, but I don't think opening this up in the meantime on a technicality is really helpful

Comment: @DoubleAA I feel like if this question was asked as a standalone it would generate sufficiently different and more specific answers that would be useful to our community and the internet as a whole.