# Is there anyplace online where I can find the te'amim for Iyov, Mishlei, and Tehillim?

Tags: tanach, trop-cantillation, job-iyov-book-of, mishlei, tehillim

Is there anyplace online where I can find a reliable recording for the te'amim for Iyov, Mishlei, and Tehillim?

Comment: What nusach are you looking for?

Comment: any, but the more the better.

Answer (score 1):

Syrian; 
https://pizmonim.org/taamim.php 
https://pizmonim.org/section.php?maqam=Iyob 
https://pizmonim.org/maqam.php?maqam=Mishle 
https://pizmonim.org/section.php?maqam=Tehillim 
found the above and some others through [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1129/why-do-the-sifrei-emes-i-e-job-proverbs-psalms-have-cantillation-marks)

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mk3pjswfc7nie8o/TaameiEmet.zip https://hebrewbooks.org/30700 https://archive.org/details/treatiseonacpoet00wickuoft/