# Chamisha Ve'esrim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows twenty-five?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. After about one business day, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: Prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1215/arbaa-veesrim-mi-yodeya?r=SearchResults

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1265/shisha-veesrim-mi-yodeya?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 7, accepted):

25 is the year [Yehezkel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Ezekiel#Vision_of_the_Temple_in_Jerusalem) prophesied the 3rd Temple. In said Temple, the gate was 25 amot wide, and there were 25 steps up to the heikhal.

Comment: Speedily in our days, Amen. Also, that's some pretty heavy 25-ness.

Answer (score 8):

25 are the stops of the Israelites in the desert when they reached ["Chashmonah."](http://bible.ort.org/books/pentd2.asp?ACTION=displaypage&BOOK=4&CHAPTER=33#C3624)  Which echoes of Chanukah.

Answer (score 6):

25 is the number of people in the family of [R' Akiva of Ofen](http://www.geni.com/people/Akiva-HaCohen-Katz/6000000000348799904) (himself, twelve sons, and twelve sons-in-law) who used to recite the Priestly Blessing together. R' Akiva used to say that he was thereby fulfilling the Torah's commandment, "Thus (כה - equals 25) shall you bless the Children of Israel...."

Answer (score 6):

25 is the number of letters (making up the names of six of the tribes) on each of the *shoham* (onyx?) stones on the shoulder straps of the Kohen Gadol's *efod* (apron). (Ex. 28:9ff; Rambam, Hil. Klei Hamikdash 9:9)

Answer (score 6):

The 25th word of the [Torah](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0101.htm) is the first occurance of "אוֹר" - "light," a possible allusion to [Chanuka](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanukkah).

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/12570/759

Answer (score 6):

25 limbs for which a (female) Canaanite slave is set free if her owner cuts them off (Rashi on Shmot 21:27; Kiddushin 25a)

Answer (score 2):

25 are the letters in "Shema Yisrael Hashem Elokeinu Hashem Echad", mirrored by the 25 letters in "Baruch Shem Kvod Malchuso L'Olam Va'ed."  The [two Shoham stones](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1239/chamisha-veesrim-mi-yodeya/1244#1244) represent Hashem Echad on one side, U'Shmo Echad on the other side.  All that's left is to connect it to the Choshen HaMishpat, which is needed to keep the Jewish people together as one!

(Adapted from the Malbim's essay "ramazei haMishkan.")

Comment: Forgive me, but Baruch shem kavod etc. only totals 24. Am I mistaken or is there an exception I'm unaware of?

Comment: The Zohar answers your query in parshat Terumah, p. 2:139b.

Answer (score 2):

25 is the age at which Levi'im are counted and begin their service in the Temple.  They then served for 25 years.

25 was the age of Chizkiyahu when he began to rule.

Answer (score 1):

25 years is the statute of limitations for a widow or her heirs to collect a ketubah in certain circumstances. See Ketubot 104a.

Answer (score 1):

25 is the day of the month of Kislev in which we celebrate חנוכה.