# Shelosha Ushloshim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows thirty-three?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. After about one business day, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1408/shnayim-ushloshim-mi-yodeya

Comment: next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1474/arbaa-ushloshim-mi-yodeya?r=SearchResults&s=3|57.4145

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Daf 33(b) in Shabbos](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=33b&format=pdf) is where the story of Lag BaOmer (Rashbi's cave) is told

Comment: Checkmark for cool coincidence.

Comment: @IsaacMoses eh. Vilna shas was a printing convention. May have been intentional...

Comment: What does the Gemara have to do with Lag Baomer?

Answer (score 8):

33 are the side chambers (*tzela'os*) surrounding the Sanctuary, in the third Beis Hamikdash ([Ez. 41:6](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1241.htm#6)).

Answer (score 7):

1. Of the 70 souls that went down to Egypt with Jacob, 33 were from his wife Leah (Bereishis 46:15).
2. The 33 days of pure blood after the birth of a male child (Vayikra 12: 4)

Answer (score 4):

The 33rd day of the Omer is a festive day.

Comment: * facepalm* sheesh

Comment: @SethJ  ....... ?

Comment: You know what Lag stands for, right?

Comment: @SethJ, better now?

Comment: @msh210 IIRC Sephardim still have nihugei aveilut on the 33rd. Not so festive for them!

Comment: Source? [15 characters]

Comment: @mevaqesh Do you need a source for the original version of this answer or its current form?

Comment: The current form. (not that I need a source, just that it would be improved with one).

Answer (score 4):

King David ruled in Jerusalem for 33 years [(Shmuel2 5:5)](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15865)

> וּבִירוּשָׁלַםִ מָלַךְ שְׁלֹשִׁים וְשָׁלֹשׁ שָׁנָה

Answer (score 2):

33 are the original masechtos that have a Gemara Talmud Bavli on them (Bava Kama, Metzia, and Basra were originally one large masechta called Maseches Nezikin, and Makkos was originally the end of Maseches Sanhedrin)

Comment: What of Shekalim, which is Yerushalmi?

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt Thus I didn't count it...

Comment: I wasn't sure, that's why I asked, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

In Diaspora, 33 *hakafot* are made between the start of Succot and the end of Simchat Torah, if you include those that have the minhag to do *Hakafot* on *Shmini Atzeret* night as well. Here's how this works:

On each day of Succot, 1 hakafah is done. Of the first 6 days, one is always on Shabbat, where no hakafah is done that day. So, that totals 5

On Hoshanah Rabba - 7 hakafot
Shemini Atzeret night - 7 hakafot
Simchat Torah night - 7 hakafot
Simchat Torah day - 7 hakafot

Total= 33

Answer (score 1):

33 days from when Moshe died (7 Adar) to when Bnei Yisrael entered the land of Israel (10 Nisan) (which perhaps means that the last of the manna to fall before Moshe died lasted for 33 days).