# Arba'a Ushloshim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows thirty-four?

### ארבעה ושלושים - מי יודע?‏

The traditional Passover song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea) implies a possible presupposition that there is a Jewish significance to be found for each [natural number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number). Accordingly, there is an [ongoing series](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) on Mi Yodeya that is attempting to unearth significant Judaism facts about each number, in sequence.

What significant Judaism facts are there about the number 34? The more significant within Judaism and the more intrinsically dependent on the value 34, the stronger the answer. Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Answers that are just lazy gematria are poor; please don't post them.

Comment: prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1434/shelosha-ushloshim-mi-yodeya

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1489/17423

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yaakov Avinu spent a total of 34 years with Yosef: the first 17 Yaakov provided for Yosef; the last 17 Yosef provided for Yaakov. [See Chizkuni on Genesis 47:28.](https://www.sefaria.org/Chizkuni%2C_Genesis.47.28.2)

Comment: I believe it's verse 28.

Comment: @Kfir Thanks, I fixed it now

Answer (score 7):

34 perakim in Devarim

Comment: And also the number of pesuchos (open) parashiyos in this book (Rambam, Hil. Sefer Torah, ch. 8).

Comment: Checkmark for collaboration on another cool coincidence.

Comment: "Perakim" are not a Jewish concept.

Answer (score 4):

34 is the age to which Doeg lived. (Sanhedrin 69b and 106b)

He was a brilliant Torah scholar but morally corrupt, and a major nemesis of King David. The Mishnah (ibid. 90a) lists him as one of the people who lost his share in the World to Come for his misdeeds, although an opinion in the Gemara there (ibid. 104b-105a, "dorshei reshumos") states that G-d gave it back to him.

Answer (score 4):

34 was the age of [Ever](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eber) when he became father to [Peleg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peleg) ([Gen 11:16](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.11.16?lang=bi)).

Answer (score 3):

According to [O.C. 493:2](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14169&st=&pgnum=196), during the Omer period, one must refrain from haircuts until the 34th day of the Omer. (I know that there are varying opinions on this, but, I'm citing one of them.)

Answer (score 3):

King Solomon was the 34th generation.

אדם שת אנוש קינן מהללאל ירד חנוך מתושלח למך נח שם ארפכשד שלח עבר פלג רעו שרוג נחור תרח 
 אברהם יצחק יעקב יהודה פרץ חצרון רם עמינדב נחשון צלמון בועז עובד ישי דוד
שלמה

Answer (score 2):

The word עברי meaning "Hebrew" and its associated forms עבריים, עבריות, etc. appear in the Tanakh 34 times.

(Excluding one appearance as a proper name of the son of Merari, DH"A 24:27)

Comment: I believe Shiloh ismentioned 34 times in the Tanach as well as ervah as a noun.

Answer (score 1):

[Avoda Zara 9a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9582&st=&pgnum=17) says that the Persian Kingdom lasted 34 years after the building of the Bais Hamikdash.

> מלכות פרס בפני הבית ל״ד שנה

Comment: though the accuracy of this is dubious https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_years_%28Jewish_calendar%29

Comment: what does this have to with judaism?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a weird one, but the Talmud ([Niddah 30b](https://www.sefaria.org/Niddah.30b.2/he/Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli?lang=he&with=Chokhmat%20Shlomo&lang2=he)) discusses the case of a woman who has a menstrual discharge on the thirty-fourth day after presumed conception, and again on the forty-first, there's doubt about whether she is in a state of niddah for the next seven days. [Rambam](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Forbidden_Intercourse.10.21?lang=he) also holds to this ruling.

Answer (score 0):

In [Fulda - a city in Hesse Germany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fulda) in December 1235 - [34 Jews were burned to death](http://dbs.bh.org.il/place/fulda) in a blood libel.

Comment: seems like jews not judaism.