# Chamisha Ushloshim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows thirty-five?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. After about one business day, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: Prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1474/17423

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1516/17423

Answer (score 4, accepted):

35 are the soldiers of the haganah who were killed on January 16th, 1948 while traveling on foot to reinforce and resupply the Gush Etzion kibbutzim.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convoy_of_35

Comment: Checkmark for strong 35-ness and inyana deyoma.

Answer (score 6):

35 gold denarii is the fine levied on one who embarrasses a Torah scholar, whether by word or by action. (Rambam, Hil. Chovel Umazik 3:5)

Rambam goes on to say (ibid. :6) that he witnessed such rulings being handed down in his native Spain (in the 12th century). However, Rema (Yoreh De'ah 243:7) cites later authorities (from the 14th-15th centuries) who say that today there are no longer any scholars of such stature, and that therefore this rule is no longer applied (although a beis din should still impose other penalties for such behavior).

Answer (score 6):

35 are the books of Tanach as they would appear in a scroll.

While we usually count 24 (counting the [Twelve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelve_minor_prophets) as one), Yoreh Deah 283:1 specifies that when writing one giant Tanach scroll, the same multi-space break between books is also used between sub-books of the Twelve.  So 35 blocks of text altogether.

(Poor Nechemiah, no book for him, YD 283 doesn't even mention his name.)

Comment: The Twelve do actually count as separate books for purposes of writing them. Three blank lines of space are used to separate one book of Neviim from the next (when they're all written in one large scroll), and the same amount of space is used to separate each of the Trei Asar. (Shulchan Aruch, Yoreh De'ah 283:1)

Comment: Excellent.  That helps a lot, I'm rewriting my answer accordingly.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Alex; I was looking right at the pdf; don't know why I wrote 384 instead of 283.

Answer (score 4):

35 is the age at which someone whose body hasn't manifested the physical signs of maturity is considered a "סריס חמה" even though they don't otherwise have the physical symptoms of being a סריס חמה. From Yevamos 97a:

> שמע מינה וכי לא נולדו לו סימני סריס עד כמה תני דבי רבי חייא עד רוב שנותיו

which is interpreted by Maimonides in הלכות אישות 2:11 to be 35 years old.

Answer (score 2):

35 are the entries in [Megillat Ta'anit](http://www.sefaria.org/Megillat_Taanit?lang=bi).

Answer (score 2):

Yehoshafat was thirty five years old when he was anointed King [(Melachim1 22:42)](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15906)

> יְהוֹשָׁפָט בֶּן שְׁלשִׁים וְחָמֵשׁ שָׁנָה בְּמָלְכוֹ

Answer (score 0):

Thirty-five Words in "ויכולו" and Thirty-five Words in the Beracha of Kiddush

http://havolim.blogspot.com/2010/02/kiddush-friday-night-minhag-avos-versus.html?m=1

Answer (score 0):

The Talmud (Kiddushin 71a) also limits who may be taught the forty-two-letter esoteric Name of God. Rav warns that it should only be taught to a person who is modest, humble, is not easily angered, does not get drunk and does not hold a grudge; additionally, he must be at “half his years,” understood by Rashi in Sanhedrin to mean thirty-five years old.