# Shiv'a Ushloshim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows thirty-seven?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. After about one business day, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: Prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1516/17423

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1544/17423

Answer (score 5, accepted):

37 were the years that King Yehoyachin spent in prison in Babylonia ([II Kings 25:27](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Kings.25.27?lang=bi), [Jer. 52:31](https://www.sefaria.org/Jeremiah.52.31?lang=bi)).

Answer (score 5):

37 were King David's mighty men ([II Sam. 23:23-39](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Samuel.23.23-39?lang=bi)).

Answer (score 4):

From yesterday, 37 months in 3 Hebrew years (usually)

Answer (score 2):

37 is the ordinal-value (alef = 1 ... tav = 22) [gematria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gematria#Methods) of "חכמה" (wisdom) and the reverse (in decimal representation) of the regular (1 ... 400) gematria of the same word (73).

Also, if you multiply it by 3, you get 111.

Comment: See also: http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/2450/shelosha-veshivim-mi-yodeya/2451#2451

Answer (score 2):

According to Pirkei D'Rav Eliezer 31 - Yitzchok was 37 years old at the time of the Akeida.

Answer (score 1):

Thirty-seven is the word לז, "that."

Many languages have different words for "this" (something close), "that" (something further), and even "that thing far over there."

My impression is that we have "zeh/zot" which gets used most of the time (with a lot of discussion whether "zu/zo" is a variant of this, something else, an Aramaic version, etc.); but occasionally biblically, Talmudically, and even later,  לז was used as "that over there", but it never really became a popular word.  Does anyone know anything about this?

Examples:

- [Genesis 24:65](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/k/k0124.htm)
- [II Kings 4:25](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94%3a%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%91_%D7%93_%D7%9B%D7%94)
- [Ezekiel 36:35](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/k/k1236.htm)
- [Makos 2:2](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%9E%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%91_%D7%91)
- Taharos [4:3](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%98%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%93_%D7%92) and [6:5](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%98%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%95_%D7%94)
- [Rambam Ishus 17:19](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/4117.htm)

Comment: Rashbam (to Gen. 24:65 and 37:19) states that indeed "laz(eh)" means "that thing (or person) far away over there." In the latter place he contrasts them using French terms: "halazeh" = "c'il," for something far away; "hazeh" = "c'est," for something right at hand.

Answer (score 1):

37 is the second part of the Sod HaRatzon which is the 50 Shaarei Binah made up of 13 and 37 (Aderes Eliyahu in Parshas Ha'azinu verse 3).

Answer (score 0):

37 is of blessed memory. (ז"ל)

Comment: Up voted for its relevance to Parasha Vayeira and Chayei Sarah. Isaac was 37 at the Akeidah. Midrash records that his neshama departed from him, thus being dead. Yishmael was 137 when he died.