# Tish'a Ushloshim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows thirty-nine?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. After about one business day, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: Prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1544/17423

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1608/17423

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 39 *Avos Melachos* (Primary types of Forbidden labor) on Shabbos (Shabbos 7:2 , Mishneh Torah (Shabbos) 7:1)

Comment: I should get 39 upvotes for every one of yours:)

Comment: Helvai that we should have so many users!

Comment: Checkmark for not being afraid to go with the most familiar and bring sources.

Comment: @IsaacMoses now there are many more than that

Answer (score 5):

The maximum number of lashes one may receive (I'll try to add sources)

Comment: Except according to Rabi Yehudah who holds 40! Makkos, 6b

Comment: Do you mean 40 factorial?!

Comment: Sorry. I meant "Except according to Rabi Yehudah who holds 40! Makkos, 22a" and not factorial!

Answer (score 3):

39 was the righteous King Yoshiyahu's age when he was killed in battle. He was crowned king at age 8, and ruled 31 years. (II Kings 22:1)

Answer (score 3):

39 was Shmuel's age when he succeeded to the leadership of the Jewish People, after the death of Eli Hakohen. (Rashi to I Sam. 1:22)

Answer (score 3):

According to a common custom, a thread is wound around the others thirty-nine times on each tassel of *tzitzis*: seven times in the first wound segment, then eight, then eleven, and finally thirteen.

Answer (score 1):

39 Toledot melacha for each Av melacha on Shabbat.

Comment: Not sure I understand.  You mean each Av has its own 39 toledot (holy toledot!)?  Is there a source for that?  Or each Av has only 1?  The example I recall is "planting" has: watering, fertilizing, and grafting.  That's neither 1 nor 39.

Comment: Woops, I forgot pruning.  But even so.  1 < Toledot < 39.

Comment: Yes, 39 for each of the 39, making 1521 toledot, plus 39 avot, for a total of 1560. I think it is a Tosefos in perek Klal Gadol in masechet Shabbos, but can't find it right now, and Google only pointed me to a messianic Judiasm site in the UK.

Comment: Yerushalmi Shabbat Ch. 7, halakhah 1 (9b)

Answer (score 1):

After Adam ate from the forbidden fruit, Hashem gave 39 curses:

10 to the serpent
10 to Adam
10 to Eve
9 to the earth

(Tikkunei Zohar 64-5)

Answer (score 1):

39 was the age at which the Ramchal died (1707-1746).

Answer (score 1):

The categories of work used to build (and use?) the Mishkan (Shabbat 49b)

Also the number of times the Torah uses the words מלאכה, מלאכתו, מלאכת (also Shabbat 49b)