# Shnayim Ve'arba'im - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows forty-two?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point in the next few days, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: Not an actual answer, but- 42 is the gematria of גוגל, or in English, Google.

Comment: Prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1631/17423

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1652/17423

Answer (score 11, accepted):

42 travels (of B'nei Yisrael) in the Torah.

מ״ב מסעות בתורה רעמםם סוכות איתם
כו׳ במדבר ל״ג

[מם׳ סופרים פ״ב ה״ו](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20137&st=%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%A8+%D7%9B%D7%93&pgnum=85&hilite=0b4df3da-4613-45e2-9060-2510bf22d483)

Comment: Checkmark for strong 42-ness, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 11):

42 details in the Menorah. (22 "cups", 11 "globes", 9 flowers)

מ״ב דברים במנורה כ״ב גביעים י״א
כפתורים ט׳ פרחים

[(עי׳ במע״ר במעשה
המשכן)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20137&st=%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%A8+%D7%9B%D7%93&pgnum=85&hilite=0b4df3da-4613-45e2-9060-2510bf22d483)

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1007196/jewish/Beit-Habechirah-Chapter-3.htm

Answer (score 11):

42 are the minimum (and today, pretty much the standard) customary number of lines per column in a Torah scroll. (Shulchan Aruch, Yoreh De'ah 275:6 in Hagah)

Comment: Some opinions say 48 is the minimum. Common sense would dictate to use at least 48 to satisfy both opinions (and it's cheaper since you use less Klaf).

Comment: Interestingly, the first printed Bible used 42 lines too https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gutenberg_Bible#Substantially_complete_copies_of_the_42-line_Bible

Answer (score 9):

42 are the years during which the royal houses of the Judean and Israelite (Ten Tribes) kingdoms were related by marriage.

This was displeasing to Hashem, since the former were righteous and the latter were not (and indeed, some of the Judean kings became corrupt under their in-laws' influence). The result was that almost all of David's descendants were wiped out, with only one infant (Yehoram) being spared. ([Seder Olam Rabbah ch. 17](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34250&st=&pgnum=70), explaining II Chron. 22:2 - cited in the commentaries ad loc.)

Answer (score 8):

42 occurences of the name of Hashem in both *tefillin*.

מ״ב אזכרות בתפלין של יד ושל ראש
כ״א בד׳ פרשיות

(הקדמת ת״ז)

http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20137&st=%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%A8+%D7%9B%D7%93&pgnum=85&hilite=0b4df3da-4613-45e2-9060-2510bf22d483

Answer (score 8):

The number of words in אנא בכח.

Comment: ... whose first letters make up the holy 42 letter name of Hashem.

Answer (score 7):

42 cities of refuge which did not give refuge to the unintentional killer without his awareness (Makkos 10a).

Answer (score 6):

42 are the korbonos that Balak brought.

7 bulls and 7 rams in each of three different locations, as recorded in:

- [Bamidbar 23:1](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9951#v=1)
- [Bamidbar 23:14](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9951#v=14)
- [Bamidbar 23:29](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9951#v=29)

Answer (score 6):

[Rus Rabah 2:8](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37460&st=&pgnum=104) says that the fellow that was watching the reapers in Boaz's field, was watching 42 reapers.

Answer (score 4):

The number of words in *birkas hatzadikim* in *Sh'monah Esre* (according to the סידורים of the word-counting genre)

Answer (score 3):

42 is the source.

(*V'dibarta* ***Bam***= 42)

Comment: No kidding. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/vdibarta-bam

Comment: Our Imma (אמא) 

Answer (score 2):

The Or HaChaim HaKadosh brings 42 elucidatioms on the beginning verse of Bechukosai.