# Shelosha Ve'arba'im - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows forty-three?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point in the next few days, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: Prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1641/17423

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1667/17423

Answer (score 6, accepted):

43 are the number of words in Esther 8:9, the longest verse in Tanach.

Comment: Note that Chazal require a Get be written "Persian style", i.e. with great verbosity.  A verse like this one demonstrates it beautifully!

Comment: Where's that requirement stated?

Comment: Hm; still trying to track it down.  Something I remembered from a long time ago.  Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 6):

43 are the degrees Celsius for R' Moshe Feinstein's lower threshold of [yad soledes bo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yad_soledet_bo)   (Igros Moshe OC IV:74).

*Yes, I can and will shamelessly switch units of measurement in search of a convenient number.  No, I don't honestly think this will beat Alex's awesome answer.*

---

43 are the thousands in the tribe of Reuben at the final census in the desert.  (Numbers 26:7).

43,730 specifically.  In the first census (Numbers Ch. 1), only one tribe, Gad, has a number that's not an even hundred.  In this census, again only one tribe, this time it's Reuben.

Did different tribes round differently?  Did only values very close to 50 (or 30?) round to that?  Do we know?

Oh right, the [answer to everything](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1641/shnayim-vearbaim-mi-yodeya/1648#1648) was yesterday.

Answer (score 4):

1)
[זבחים מב ב](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%96%D7%91%D7%97%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9E%D7%91_%D7%90)

> אבל דמים הניתנין על המזבח הפנימי כגון ארבעים ושלש של יום הכיפורים

There were forty-three "sprinkling" of blood onto the inner altar on Yom Kippur.

2)  The amount of פתוחות in ספר בראשית. (The amount of "paragraphs" in a Torah scroll for the Book of Genesis.)

See here: http://www.daat.ac.il/encyclopedia/value.asp?id1=2312

3) Forty-three commentaries in the [standard edition](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14126&pgNum=2) of [Mikraot Gedolot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikraot_Gedolot).

4) The amount of times the name יששכר appears in תנ"ך. (Try it here: http://www.snopi.com/ToraSearch/torasearch.asp)

Comment: 3 seems irrelevant.

Comment: Not really. Not that the initials of מקראות גדולות are מ"ג which is 43. So it's most significant! :)

Comment: Ephraim: lol :)

Answer (score 1):

You **also** (גם) want an answer for 43?

Comment: גם zeh l'tova..

Answer (score 0):

43 is a big number (גדול is 43).