# Arba'a Ve'arba'im - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows forty-four?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point in the next few days, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: Prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1652/17423

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1688/17423

Answer (score 8, accepted):

44 Candles (or little oil capsules) in a box for Hannukah.

Comment: Including shamashes.

Comment: that is why I was m'dayak on "in a box" as opposed to "for a week of lighting"

Comment: Checkmark for classic 44-ness.

Comment: these classic answers are getting harder to come by, for sure.

Answer (score 4):

44 is גאם, the Greek letter gamma (Γ).  Chazal use it often when describing a shape of two perpendicular lines.  Such as:

- The path taken through Israel by the spies (Rashi to Numbers 13:21)
- Describing the shape of 2 sukkah walls (Rashi Sukah 7a s.v. shtai defanos)
- Which barrels of wine in your cellar you need to check for Chametz, according to R' Yochanan (Pesachim 8b).  Note that this one is 3-D.

Some instances have the spelling as just גם (which would have worked for yesterday), but it looks like the spelling with the aleph is more standard.  Also works well as in modern Hebrew they call the letter gimmel-mem-aleph, but same Gematria.

Answer (score 3):

44 are the years (2884-2928) that the Mishkan stood in Giveon. (Zevachim 118b-119a; Yerushalmi, Megillah 1:12)

Answer (score 3):

44 days of rain in Jerusalem in an [average year](http://www.jerusalem-insiders-guide.com/weather-in-jerusalem.html)

Answer (score 0):

Leah lived for 44 years.(B'N Ill source later)

Leah and Rachel were 22 yrs old at marriage. They are twins - Seder Olam Rabbah

(22x2=44)
Though I struggle with how the deception with Leah renders Rachel married as well. More like 'as if'?

Comment: Er....22x4 = 88?

Comment: Oops. Dont MiYodeya and drive.