# Shisha Ve'arba'im - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows forty six?

### ששה וארבעים - מי יודע?‏

The traditional Passover song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea) implies a possible presupposition that there is a Jewish significance to be found for each [natural number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number). Accordingly, there is an [ongoing series](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) on Mi Yodeya that is attempting to unearth significant Judaism facts about each number, in sequence.

What significant Judaism facts are there about the number 46? The more significant within Judaism and the more intrinsically dependent on the value 46, the stronger the answer. Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

And from lazy gematria, please don't try to base your entire answer.

Comment: Number in shevet gad in bamidbar 1:25 is 45650, which rounds to 46000... close

Comment: Prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1688/17423

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1727/17423

Answer (score 5, accepted):

46 are the chapters in each of the [first](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%22%D7%9D_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%91%D7%94_%D7%99) [two](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%22%D7%9D_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94_%D7%92) books of the Rambam's Mishneh Torah.

Answer (score 3):

46 is the other day in the omer with that funny base 7 base 10 thing:
[Shelosha Ve'esrim - mi yodeya?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1161/shelosha-veesrim-mi-yodeya/1162#1162)

Answer (score 1):

See [Ba'er Hetev](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14169&st=&pgnum=197) note #8 on O.C. 493. He cites Magen Avraham that states that it has become custom to allow people to marry during *Shloshet Yemei Hagbala*, which is for a 3 day span before Shavuot. This would mean that it beginning on the 46th day of the Omer  people who observe the latter portion of Omer mourning practices (i.e., beginning from Rosh Hodesh Iyar) may get married.

Comment: Isn't it beginning on the 47th?

Answer (score -2):

The 46th passuk in bamidbar is the one that counts all of the male 20 to 60 Jews as 603550

Comment: Why is this significant?

Comment: @DoubleAA admittedly it it quite a stupid answer. My original thought was that this is the sum of klal yisrael I.e. when we come together and it is thereby significant