# Shiv'a Ve'arba'im - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows forty-seven?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point in the next few days, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: Prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1698/17423

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1752/17423

Answer (score 5, accepted):

47 are the prohibitory mitzvos in the Torah portion of Ki Teitzei (according to the Chinuch's listing) - the most in any one portion.

47 are also the positive mitzvos in the Rambam's Sefer Ha'Avodah (dealing with the laws of the Temple) - again, the most in any one book of his Mishneh Torah.

Answer (score 1):

47 are the verses in [Nachum](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t19.htm).​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 1):

R Yossi Haglili says: After Scripture equates the deed of the land of Egypt with that of the land of Canaan, and that of the land of Canaan with that of the land of Egypt, why did the Canaanites merit remaining in their land for forty-seven years, as it is written (Bamidbar 13:22) "And Chevron (in Canaan) was built seven years before Tzoan (in) Egypt" (and add forty years for their sojourn in the desert)? It was because they honored our father Abraham, saying (Bereshith 23:5) "Hear us, my lord, a prince of G d are you in our midst" — wherefore they merited remaining on their land forty-seven years.
[*Sifra*](https://www.sefaria.org/Sifra%2C_Acharei_Mot%2C_Section_8.6?lang=bi).

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Sefer HaYashar](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaYashar_(midrash)%2C_Book_of_Genesis%2C_Vayishlach.11?ven=Sefer_ha-Yashar,__trans._Edward_B.M._Browne,_New_York,_1876&lang=bi), Shimon and Levi captured 47 men in Shechem and killed the rest, following what happened with Dinah.