# Shemona Ve'arba'im - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows forty-eight?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point in the next few days, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: Prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1727/17423

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/tisha-vearbaim-mi-yodeya?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 3, accepted):

48 traits with which Torah is attained ([Avot 6:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.6.6?lang=bi))
(see also #30 and #24 in the mi yodeya series)

Comment: Checkmark for 48-ness and source.

Answer (score 4):

48 are the tractates of the Mishnah (out of 63) that have some Gemara, either Bavli or Yerushalmi (or both).

Answer (score 3):

48 levitical cities (six cities of refuge and 42 others), per Numbers 35.

Answer (score 2):

48 years between Yovel's, according to the opinion that the 50th year is Yovel, and also the first year of the next shemita cycle.
In other words, the longest you can own a house outside you shevet is 48 years.

Answer (score 1):

48 is the second in a series of two consecutive days' shirim shel yom whose chapter number is exactly 24 times the day of the week on which it is recited. (The first one is on Sunday.)

Answer (score 1):

48 are the verses in [Yonah](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t17.htm).​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 1):

48 are the customary minimum number of lines of text per column in a Sefer Torah (some say 42).

Source: [Rema Yoreh Deah 275:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De'ah.275.6)

Comment: 48 used to be alot more popular than it is nowadays.

Comment: @DoubleAA what's the popular amount nowadays?

Comment: 42, like the other option you said