# Tish'a Ve'arba'im - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows forty-nine?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point in the next few days, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: Prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1752/17423

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/chamishim-mi-yodeya?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 5, accepted):

49 are the times that Nevuchadnetzar performed divination to see whether he'd be successful in conquering Jerusalem; each time Hashem made the results consistently show that it would be so. (Rashi to Ezekiel 21:28)

Answer (score 5):

49 are the days of the Omer.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/70672

Answer (score 1):

The Jews were in 49 levels of Tumah when they left Mitzrayim

Answer (score 1):

[Vayikra 25:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.25.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> וְסָפַרְתָּ לְךָ שֶׁבַע שַׁבְּתֹת שָׁנִים שֶׁבַע שָׁנִים שֶׁבַע פְּעָמִים וְהָיוּ לְךָ יְמֵי שֶׁבַע שַׁבְּתֹת הַשָּׁנִים ***תֵּשַׁע וְאַרְבָּעִים*** שָׁנָה׃
>
> You shall count off seven weeks of years—seven times seven years—so that the period of seven weeks of years gives you a total of **forty-nine** years.

Answer (score 1):

Moshe himself entreated God
for clarity, but God refused, transmitting instead forty-nine aspects of purity and forty-nine aspects of impurity.
Yerushalmi, Sanhedrin 4:2, Pesikta Rabbati 21:14-5, Midrash Shoḥar Tov 12:4, and
Masekhet Sofrim 16:5.

Answer (score 0):

49 = the number of *dafim* in maseches [Shevuot](https://www.sefaria.org/Shevuot?lang=bi) & maseches [Sotah](https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah?lang=bi)*

*colloquially speaking, as technically every daf starts on **.ב** (ie there are literally 48)

Comment: I'm not sure the colloquial number of pages in some printing of a book is that fundamental to Judaism

Comment: @DoubleAA there does seem to be precedence for it in the series https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/5648/18474 but can delete if you think I should

Comment: I haven't upvoted that one either. Interesting can be subjective but at least I'm consistent