# Echad Vachamishim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows fifty-one?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point in the next few days, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: Prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1808/17423

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1879/shnayim-vachamishim-mi-yodeya?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 3, accepted):

51 are the mitzvos that the Rambam enumerates as related to avodah zarah (idolatry) - the most of any one section of halachos in his Mishneh Torah.

Answer (score 2):

Psalm 27 (לדוד ה אורי) is said during 51 days of the year, outside Israel, according to many Nusach Ashkenaz and Sefard.

It is said staring on 1 Ellul and continues until Shemini Atzeret. 29 days in Elul + 22 days during Tishrei = 51.

Comment: In Israel it is not said on Shmini Atzeret, since they don't sit in the Sukkah then. (Same should hold for many in Chu'l as well.)

Comment: Not all Nusach Ashkenaz communities say it at all. It was pretty controversial when first introduced, though recently it's caught on, what with being in Artscroll and all...

Answer (score 0):

The Torah was given on the 51st day, the 7th of Sivan.