# Shnayim Vachamishim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows fifty-two?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point in the next few days, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: Prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1827/17423

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1899/shelosha-vachamishim-mi-yodeya?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Moed Katan 28a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9689&st=&pgnum=55) says that Shmuel lived for fifty two years. [Sifri - on the last page - line 9](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34327&st=&pgnum=171&hilite=) lists six pairs that had the same lifespan. One of them is Shmuel and Shlomo. Thus Shlomo HaMelech also lived for fifty two years.

See also [Aish.com](http://www.aish.com/jl/h/cc/48937102.html) regarding the age of Shlomo HaMelech when he died.

> Born in 848 BCE, Solomon dies at age 52 in 796 BCE, ruling as king for
>   40 years

Answer (score 4):

52 is the numerical value of one of the possible expansions of Hashem's Four-Lettered Name (known as מילוי ההי"ן, because the two letters ה are each expanded to ה"ה). It is known as שם ב"ן, and is associated with the lower (spiritual and physical) worlds.

As an example of this, R' Shneur Zalman of Liadi observes (Shaar Hayichud Veha'emunah, end of ch. 7) that a stone, called in Hebrew אבן, ultimately derives its very limited life-force (through a tremendous number of condensations *(tzimtzumim)* of Divine energy) from this Name, "with an additional letter א from some other [Divine] Name, for a reason known to its Creator."

Answer (score 2):

52 weeks in a solar year

Answer (score 2):

misas shmuel hanavi (Moed Katan 28a)

Answer (score 2):

In the entire **Chumash** Bamidbar there are 52 Mitzvos

Comment: According to whom?

Answer (score 2):

52 are the [perakim in Yirmeyahu](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1101.htm)

Comment: I'm not sure this is a fact about Judaism...

Comment: Aren't these too?... http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4781/chamishim-umeya-mi-yodeya/4782#4782 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1474/arbaa-ushloshim-mi-yodeya/1476#1476?

Comment: The latter is equally problematic, though could be saved by including Alex's comment. The former is probably Jewish; see my link there.

Comment: I understand now. Perhaps I should delete this then...?

Answer (score 2):

Avraham was 52 when he started his goal of showing there is only one God to mankind. (Avodah Zora 9a)

Answer (score -1):

The gematria, numerical value of kalev is 52