# Chamisha Vachamishim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows fifty-five?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point in the next few days, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: Prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1937/17423

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2000/shisha-vachamishim-mi-yodeya?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 4, accepted):

55 are the years that King Menashe of Judah ruled. ([II Kings 21:1](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt09b21.htm))

Correspondingly, 55 are the number of approaches he was able to use to explain the Book of Vayikra ([Sanhedrin 103b](http://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.103b.10?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all)).

An outstanding Torah scholar (see also ibid. 102b), he was nevertheless one of the most wicked Jewish kings (at least until he did teshuvah); according to the majority opinion (ibid. 90a), he lost his share in the World to Come for his actions.

Answer (score 2):

55 days from the original shabbos hagadol (10 Nissan) until kabbalas haTorah (assuming 6 Sivan).

Answer (score 2):

55 are the prophets of Israel (mentioned in Gemara [Megilah 14a](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94_%D7%99%D7%93_%D7%90))

Answer (score 1):

55 are the verses in [Malachi](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t24.htm).​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​