# Shemona Vachamishim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows fifty-eight?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point in the next few days, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: Prev: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2034/17423

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2096/tisha-vachamishim-mi-yodeya?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 7, accepted):

58 are the years that Noach and Avraham were contemporaries (1948-2006 since Creation). Appropriately enough, the gematria of the name נח is 58.

Comment: Nice coincidence! Did you see it somewhere or just notice it?

Comment: I've just looked it up. It's in Ibn Ezra's commentary to Gen. 6:9.

Answer (score 0):

"Even in the Megillah itself, where Hashem's name is not mentioned a single time and He appears to have abandoned us, He is still there protecting us through Mordechai and Esther. The Rokeach points out that Haman's name appears 54 times in the Megillah, and the Vilna Gaon notes that there are 54 letters in the names of Haman's 10 sons who were hanged on the gallows. Correspondingly, Esther's name also appears 54 times. Memuchan, which is Haman's other name, appears once, as does Esther's alias, Hadassah. While Haman's name appears 54 times, the name of his wife Zeresh is mentioned only four times. To allude to Mordechai's ability to thwart them, his name appears 58 times."

https://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/alport/archives/tetzave77.htm