# Why does Chinuch confuse Parashat Nitzavim and Vayelech?

Tags: mitzvah, vayelech, hakhel, sefer-hachinuch

[image]

Why does [this edition of] Minchas Chinuch list the two Mitzvos of Parashat Vayelech under Parashat Nitzavim?

Answer (score 14):

Parashat Vayelekh isn't formally a thing. There is Parashat Nitzavim, and in some years it is read over two weeks. When that happens some people have started calling the second half "Parashat Vayelekh" after its incipit. But it's not traditionally part of the count of official sections.

This follows from the traditional count of 53 sections in the Babylonian annual Torah cycle ([Zohar](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/70620/759), [Saadya Gaon and Rambam](http://www.hakirah.org/vol%202%20epstein.pdf), [Tanya Rabbati](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bhg6joc6cll175j/Tanya%20Rabbasi-%20Three%20Versions%20of%20Parasha%20Names.pdf?dl=0), [Machzor Vitri](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=10172&st=&pgnum=287) among others) and [the traditional count of 70 verses](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/82887/759) in this section (and no marker for a new section at "Vayelekh" in the [Aleppo Codex](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2d/Aleppo-HighRes1-Torah.pdf/page5-1240px-Aleppo-HighRes1-Torah.pdf.jpg) or the [Leningrad Codex](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/50/Leningrad-codex-05-deuteronomy.pdf/page39-1275px-Leningrad-codex-05-deuteronomy.pdf.jpg)) etc.

Historically, there are other sections (eg. Mishpatim or Chukkat) that have been split over multiple weeks in different communities under specific circumstances, so this is not an unheard of phenomenon.

Comment: What's the difference between two parshas sometimes read together and one parsha sometimes split in two? Probably nothing but tradition, perhaps dating from a time when Vezot Haberakha wasn't read in its entirety on Shmini Atzeret and there were indeed a maximum of 53 Shabbatot in the year.

Comment: A partial Nafka Mina could be if a community missed Parashat Ki Tavo, can they make it up with Nitzavim[/Vayelekh] according to the opinions that you can't read 3 sections in one week (MA 135:2)

Comment: The 'geonim' didn't use the fourth aliya to combine nitzavim and vayelekh together like by other mechubarim https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21647&st=&pgnum=197