# Is Vayelech misnumbered

Tags: mesorah-tradition, vayelech

Why is the siman for Parshat Vayelech listed as 70 if it only has 30 pesukim?

Comment: It's including Nitzavim. See here for more info:  https://web.archive.org/web/20151119045657/https://faculty.biu.ac.il/~ofery/papers/nitsavim.pdf

Comment: The siman is for the whole parsha nitzavim which is indeed 70 verses long https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/108816/759

Comment: Didn't notice it by any other double.

Comment: @Shababnik why would what be by a double? We aren't discussing double parshas but halved parshas. Nitzavim, at 70 verses long, is indeed sometimes halved.

Comment: @DoubleAA Didn't know a half parsha existed

Comment: Learn something new every day