# Shisha Veshiv'im Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred seventy-six?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The longest parasha, Naso, [has 176 pesukim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naso_%28parsha%29).

Answer (score 5):

There are 176 words in the first two paragraphs of Shema (including Baruch Shem).

Answer (score 3):

The longest chapter of Tehilim - Tehilim 119 has **176 Pesukim**

Answer (score 2):

176 is the last *daf* of the *maseches* with the most *dapim* (*Bava Basra*).

Answer (score 0):

Kel b'nei keil b'nei (from the Pesach Seder piyut) is gematria 176.

Comment: Is this significant?

Comment: Yes. Longest parsha (Written Torah) = 176 pesukim. Longest mesechta (Oral Torah) = 176 daf. Longest chapter in Tehillim (tefilla) = 176 pesukim. Through our combined efforts in all three - Written & Oral Torah and prayer - we will merit "kel b'nei kel b'nei", the building of the 3rd Beis HaMikdash.

Comment: But the longest masechta has 175 daf?

Comment: That's because Daf Alef is the Munkatcher Passport ;) .