# What does the number 40 represent?

Tags: words, number

The number 40 appears multiple times in the Torah and the works of the Sages, though in very different contexts:

For instance: [40 days of rain during the flood](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8170/jewish/Chapter-7.htm), [for 40 days, Moses was on Mount Sinai](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9895/jewish/Chapter-34.htm), [40 days before beginning of life](https://www.sefaria.org/Niddah.30b.12).

Is there any underlying principle, which would explain why the number 40 is used in all of these instances?

Comment: Hi @frozen58 and welcome to MiYodeya. What exactly do you want answering? Other examples of the number 40 or what the number 40 symbolises?

Comment: If the former - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1608/arbaim-mi-yodeya

Comment: 40 represents a metamorphosis [see here](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/137085/jewish/Mem.htm#footnoteRef9a137085). Additionaly, the letter "Mem" has a value of 40,  and has a connection to Moshiach. A Mikvah is also filled with 40 seah of water.

Comment: I think he is clearly asking about what it symbolizes. How is this question asking for examples?

Comment: What it symbolizes and what the meaning behind something is, aren't those the same questions?

Comment: 40 has to do with recreation, renewal, restart, cleansing. 40 days of the Flood to "restart" the Earth, 40 years in the desert to "restart" the Jewish people, 40 seah of water in a mikve to "rejuvenate" the person.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first answer. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: @MichoelR - looking at the initial phraseology of the question...it has since been edited

Comment: @Dov So then I don't know why an answer can't be provided, similar to several of the comments here. Sensible question, needs an answer.

Comment: Don't forget 39, which is 40

Comment: @MichoelR - I'm not doubting that, neither did I close the question. But the questioner has to confirm that this is what is asking