# Resource for dotted letters in Nakh

Tags: product-recommendation, navi-prophets, safrus, ketuvim

It is relatively easy to find a list of dotted letters in Torah.  Even a good tikkun kore will list them.

However, it's harder to find a list of these in Nakh.  Where can I find that resource?  Alternatively, where are they?

Comment: An authoritative list? These things vary among the traditions.

Comment: @DoubleAA That's information I didn't have.  Then *a* list will do.  I'd like a starter, but ideally Ashkenazi.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18402/759

Comment: For instance, check your Torah tomorrow morning, and tell me if the last letter in last week's parsha is written upside down. http://www.sofer.co.uk/html/upside_down_nun_sofit.html

Comment: @DoubleAA neat! Thanks.  I've definitely never seen that one.

Comment: @DoubleAA Is there less debate about dotted letters?  I can limit my question to just dotted letters in Nakh

Comment: Limiting to dotted, or big, or small or etc. would probably make this more easily answerable. At that point might as well just say Tanakh and get the whole list together.

Comment: @DoubleAA, that's one I hadn't heard of.

Comment: @SethJ Charles : I see neither of you has taken my recommendation http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7586409#7586409

Comment: @DoubleAA, sadly, no.

Comment: Check _Tora Sh'lema_ after _Tazria_ (or maybe after _M'tzora_)? I **think** he has a list. Not posting this as an answer, as I'm very unsure.

Comment: בראשית טז:ה יח:ט יט:לג לג:ד לז:יב במדבר ג:לט ט:י כא:ל כט:טו דברים כט:כח ש״ב יט:כ ישעיהו מד:ט יחזקאל מא:כ מו:כב
I think I got this from [here](http://www.amazon.com/Rashis-Commentary-Psalms-Mayer-Gruber/dp/0827608721).

Comment: Charles, given that the answers here address all of Tanakh, do you mind if I [generalize](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1299/759) your question to ask for that? It may be available elsewhere too, but it's also available here.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1410/759

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a shame that the Mesorah is no longer printed in most Tanachs as it was in the past. This particular question is answered by the short Mesorah on Bamidbar 3:39 where it says י' נקודות בתורה. The long Mesorah on the same verse elaborates on where the 10 dots are. It says that there are 10 in the Torah and another 5 in Nach as follows: Torah- Bereishis 16:5, 19:33, 18:9, 33:4, 37:12; Bamidbar 3:39, 9:10, 21:30, 29:15; Devarim 29:28. Nach- Shmuel2 19:20; Yechezkel 41:20; Yeshaia 44:9; Yechezkel 46:22; Tehilim 27:13

Answer (score 1):

Torah Sh'lemah has a list in parshat Tzav. מאיר עיני סופרים has one as do some editions of tanakh including one of the Breuer/Aleppo editions (Horeb?).

Source: Any given table in my yeshiva was likely to have a dozen different tanakhs on it with at least one containing any table or map you were looking for at the moment.