# Chanukah Remazim

Tags: chanuka, gematria-numerology

What are some intresting Remazim like Acronyms and Numerical equivalents (Gematrias) with the word Chanukah for some fillers for a Chanukah Party speech?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4357/donut-and-its-deeper-significance#comment38978_4357

Answer (score 6):

Roshei Teivos of Chanuka = Ches Nairos V'Halacha K'Bais Hillel

Answer (score 6):

The word Chashmonai is Roshei Teivos - Chodesh, Shabbos, Milah, Nidah, Ishus, Yichud Hashem wjich are the six Mitzvos the Yevanim wanted to eradicate. (Shaar Bas Rabim)

Answer (score 5):

Maccabe: מכבי = Mi Chamocha Ba'elim Adonai

Comment: Also Matisyahu Kohen Ben Yochanan.

Answer (score 5):

חנוכה could be split into two words: חנו+כה, which means "rested on 25". The Hashmonaim rested from the war on 25 of Kislev.

Answer (score 4):

The reason Yavan was able to take control of the Bais HaMikdash is that Yavan = 66 and Haichal = 65

Comment: I doubt that is the _reason_...

Comment: Source - Bnei Yissochor

Comment: What's your point?

Answer (score 4):

25th word in the Torah is Ohr, a hint to the miracle of Chanukah, which happened with lights on the 25th day of Kislev.

Comment: +1. There's a source for this observation. Do you know what it is, by any chance? (I don't.)

Comment: @msh210: I read it in Sefer HoToda'ah (book of our heritage), but it was the student edition and didn't bring the source.

Answer (score 3):

How about this: [Number of pesukim in the parasha of the korbanos of the nesiim (and the gematria of chanuka).](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2775/tisha-ushmonim-mi-yodeya/2777#2777)

Comment: Intriguing too.

Answer (score 2):

The Agra D'Kalla says that the word Breishis בראשית is Roshei Teivos as follows.

A: א'נטיוכות ר'שע י'גזור ת'כתבו ב'קרן ש'ור

B: י'שועה ר'בה ת'היה ב'זמן ש'ימלוך א'נטיוכות

C: י'שועה ר'בה ת'היה ש'ינצחו ב'ני א'הרן

D: ב'ימי ר'שעת י'ונים ת'הללו ש'ם א'דנות (Hallel)

E: ב'ימי ר'שעת י'ונים ת'דליקו ש'מונה א'ורות

Answer (score 1):

Gimraya of Hanuka:

- Zeh Mazal
- Milev Tov
- Ze MaHalev
- VeHaya Ki Yeviacha

Answer (score 0):

In Parshas Bereishis, the 25th word is Ohr.

In Parshas Ma'asei, the 25th stop is Chashmonah.

In Parahas Emor, immediately after the Yamim Tovim is the Menorah, a hint to Chanukah. After that is the Shulchan, a hint to Purim and its mitzvos of food.