Do Jews have to take time from work to spend requested time with their parents
According to Halacha, Jews are obligated to honor their mothers and fathers. My question is, if a mother or father requests their child spend time with them, and that would conflict with their job schedule, is that Jewish child obligated to request time off for the mitzvah of Kibbud?

Jacob also had problems to honour his parents due to a conflicting job schedule...https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22663/15256

R' Doniel Neustadt writes:

...the poskim are in agreement that when the parent’s request will cause the child a financial loss ... the child need not obey. A child is not considered to have violated his parent’s wish when he does so for a legitimate reason (and the parent does not stand to gain any material “benefit” from the child’s compliance).

If you can arrange a visit around your work schedule, there's no reason to disrupt your work to do the visit.
