# Chamisha Ve'esrim Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows two hundred twenty-five?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enosh gave birth to Kenon at 90. Kenon gave birth to Mahallalel at 70. Mahallalel gave birth to Yered at 65.

90+70+65 = 225 - Enosh was 225 years old when Yered was born.

Answer (score 1):

225 is the number of times people will say the name of a stage of the [Pesach Seder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passover_Seder#Order_of_the_Seder) if they sing through [all of them](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/808/chamisha-asar-mi-yodeya) at each stage.

Comment: Do people actually do this? Kinda hard to before _matza_. (Unless it's customary to say it then so it's considered speech related to the bread? CYLOR of course.)

Comment: I suppose that, given this consideration, it's unlikely to happen. Unless, of course, people are Machmir to get in one full singing per stage and therefore sing twice before Motzi and twice before Maror (so as not to interrupt between its beracha and eating Koreich). I feel like 15^2 ought to come up somewhere. Isn't there something whose dimensions are 15X15?

Answer (score 1):

[Reportedly](http://books.google.com/books?id=4U_OcvXvhF4C&pg=PA34&dq=225), 225 Jews were killed as alleged co-conspirators of Andrzej Kott's.

Answer (score 1):

[Reportedly](http://books.google.com/books?id=IpGzGE6UK7wC&pg=PA375&dq=larissa), 225 Jews of [Larissa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larissa) were sent to [Birkenau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auschwitz_II).