# Why was the Shulchan Aruch's ruling to wait until Lad LaOmer to cut one's hair?

Tags: sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, hair, sefirat-ha-omer, shulchan-aruch, lag-ba-omer

The Shulchan Aruch ([493:2](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A6%D7%92)) writes that one should not cut one's hair until the morning of the 34th day of the 'Omer ("אין להסתפר עד יום ל"ד בבקר"). What is the source for waiting until the morning of the 34th day?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Beit Yosef there quotes many Rishonim who have a version of the story (Yevamot 62b) that Rabbi Akiva's students died until פרוס העצרת a half [month] before Shavuot. So 49-15=34 and on the last day we say that a partial day counts as the whole day so on the 34th in the morning, the mourning ends.

Comment: Does the Shulchan Aruch's ruling apply equally to shaving?

Comment: @EfraimMatityahu Shaving, weddings, you name it. It's the same period of mourning.

Comment: So Ashkenazim and Sepharadim each have a different tradition of until when Rabbi Akiva's students. But why not cut one's hair on the night of the 34th day (i.e. right after counting 34 after Arvit)? Why wait until morning?

Comment: @LeeFogel You mean why does the rule of the partial day only take effect in the morning? It's actually a machloket rishonim by regular mourning too. Some rishonim hold Shiva ends just after Maariv on the 7th day, while others say it ends after Shacharit on the 7th day. We rule like the latter opinion. So same thing here.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/821/759