# Echad Mi Yodeya - why does it stop at 13?

Tags: number, passover, song-poetry

The song ["Echod Mi Yodeya"](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%99%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8:%D7%94%D7%92%D7%93%D7%94_%D7%A9%D7%9C_%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%97_-_%D7%90%D7%97%D7%93_%D7%9E%D7%99_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%93%D7%A2) traditionally sung at the Pesach Seder goes up to number 13. Why does this song not go higher or lower than 13?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/770/759

Comment: כנגד י״ג מידות?

Comment: The word Echod - אֶחָד - also = 13

Comment: Again, just conjecture here; but, "Keneged the 13 Middot" works pretty well with the last stanza and with the theme of Pesahh (HaShem redeeming us from Egypt).

Comment: כדי שישאלו התינוקות

Comment: I saw a video once of this song being sung in russian in front of the Lubavitcher Rebbe and the person singing it added 14 for the books of Rambam