# Who composed the Piyut Echad Mi Yodeya?

Tags: history, song-poetry, passover-seder-hagada

Who composed the [Piyut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piyyut) Echad Mi Yodeya that is commonly recited on Pesach?

Comment: Not [Isaac Moses](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/2/isaac-moses) :)

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/857

Comment: See my answer [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/26339/1569)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [Wikipedia](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%97%D7%93_%D7%9E%D7%99_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%93%D7%A2) the author is unknown.

Comment: See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea#History